# How does endianness affect enumeration values in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, porting, endianness

How does endianness affect enumeration values in C++?

Is the size of an enum dependent upon how many enumerations there are and thus some enums are 1 byte, while others are 2 or 4 bytes?

How do I put an enumeration value into network byte order from host byte order?

Comment: If this is homework (as it sounds very much like), please add "homework" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianness affects enumerations no more or less than it does other integer types.

The only guarantee on size is that it must be possible for an enum to hold values of `int`; the compiler is free to choose the actual size based on the defined members (disclaimer: this is certainly the case for C, not 100% sure for C++; I'll check...)

Answer (score 1):

Enums depend on the compiler.  They can be an 1, 2, or 4 bytes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)).  They should have the same endianness as the platform they are used on.

To put an enum value into a specific byte order you would need to know what the system you are on is and what the network expect.  Then treat as you would an int.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func) for help on conversions.

Comment: Yep.  Read only the first part.  Corrected.

Comment: So a compiler cannot choose to use 8 bytes for a 64 bit platform?

Comment: That seems to be what the spec says.  Newer specs may change that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Same way it affects everything else.
2. The compiler is free to choose the minimum required space.
3. htons(), or if you know you have more than 64k values, htonl().