# Specifying size of enum type in C

Tags: c, optimization, enums, word-size

Already read through [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/366017/513660), but was looking for something a little more specific.

- Is there a way to tell your compiler specifically how wide you want your enum to be?
- If so, how do you do it? I know how to specify it in C#; is it similarly done in C?
- Would it even be worth doing? When the enum value is passed to a function, will it be passed as an `int`-sized value regardless?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell your compiler
>   specifically how wide you want your
>   enum to be?

In general case no. Not in standard C.

> Would it even be worth doing?

It depends on the context. If you are talking about passing parameters to functions, then no, it is not worth doing (see below). If it is about saving memory when building aggregates from enum types, then it might be worth doing. However, in C you can simply use a suitably-sized integer type instead of enum type in aggregates. In C (as opposed to C++) enum types and integer types are almost always interchangeable.

> When the enum value is passed to a function, will it be passed as an int-sized value regardless?

Many (most) compilers these days pass all parameters as values of natural word size for the given hardware platform. For example, on a 64-bit platform many compilers will pass all parameters as 64-bit values, regardless of their actual size, even if type `int` has 32 bits in it on that platform (so, it is not generally passed as "int-sized" value on such a platform). For this reason, it makes no sense to try to optimize enum sizes for parameter passing purposes.

Comment: "If you are talking about passing parameters to functions, then no, it is not worth doing (see below)" Not always. If you use a 8-Bit Processor, the natural size is 8Bit, but a int and enum are at least 16bit (without -fshort-enums), so you need there at least 2 registers which can slow down functions calls.

Answer (score 30):

I believe there is a flag if you are using GCC.

> -fshort-enums

Comment: +1 Cool ... that's what I was looking for as far as forcing the compiler goes.

Comment: Or selectively `enum __attribute__ ((__packed__)) my_enum {...};`

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: will give that a try as well. I knew you could use the `__packed__` attribute on a `struct`; did not know you could also use it on an `enum`.

Comment: Here's a little more insight. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527229/4561887

Comment: As the GCC documentation says, using the flag `-fshort-enums` is dangerous since it affects _all_ enum types. Better use `__attribute__((__packed__))`.

Answer (score 14):

Even if you are writing strict `C` code, the results are going to be compiler dependent. Employing the strategies from this thread, I got some interesting results...

**enum_size.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum __attribute__((__packed__)) PackedFlags {
    PACKED = 0b00000001,
};

enum UnpackedFlags {
    UNPACKED = 0b00000001,
};

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
  printf("packed:\t\t%lu\n", sizeof(PACKED));
  printf("unpacked:\t%lu\n", sizeof(UNPACKED));
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc enum_size.c
$ ./a.out
packed:         4
unpacked:       4
```

```
$ gcc enum_size.c -fshort_enums
$ ./a.out
packed:         4
unpacked:       4
```

```
$ g++ enum_size.c
$ ./a.out
packed:         1
unpacked:       4
```

```
$ g++ enum_size.c -fshort_enums
$ ./a.out
packed:         1
unpacked:       1
```

In my example above, I did not realize any benefit from `__attribute__((__packed__))` modifier until I started using the C++ compiler.

**EDIT:**

@technosaurus's suspicion was correct.

By checking the size of `sizeof(enum PackedFlags)` instead of `sizeof(PACKED)` I see the results I had expected...

```cpp
  printf("packed:\t\t%lu\n", sizeof(enum PackedFlags));
  printf("unpacked:\t%lu\n", sizeof(enum UnpackedFlags));
```

I now see the expected results from `gcc`:

```
$ gcc enum_size.c
$ ./a.out
packed:         1
unpacked:       4
```

```
$ gcc enum_size.c -fshort_enums
$ ./a.out
packed:         1
unpacked:       1
```

Comment: Try `sizeof (enum PackedFlags)` so that the enum doesn't get extended.  You'll have similar experience with sizeof( 'a' )

Comment: @technosaurus you are correct! Why does this happen with the C compiler and not the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 14):

**As of C23**, this is finally possible in standard C:

You can put a colon and an integer type after the `enum` keyword (or after the name tag, if it's named) to specify the enum's *fixed underyling type*, which sets the size and range of the enum type.

> Would it even be worth doing? When the enum value is passed to a function, will it be passed as an int-sized value regardless?

On x86_64, the type of an integer does not influence whether it is passed in register or not (as long as it fits in a single register). The size of data on the heap however is very significant for cache performance.

Comment: reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum

Answer (score 12):

There is also another way if the enum is part of a structure:

```
enum whatever { a,b,c,d };

struct something {
   char  :0;
   enum whatever field:CHAR_BIT;
   char  :0;
};
```

The :0; can be omitted if the enum field is surrounded by normal fields. If there's another bitfield before, the :0 will force byte alignement to the next byte for the field following it.

Comment: Not even remotely; no permutation of flags I could find in `gcc` would compile it, only giving `error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘:’ token`. Zero-sized bitfields are a thing, & they must be unnamed, but they still need to have a type. I presume that a zero-sized/nameless bitfield means 'start the next non-zero-sized bitfield at the start of the next allocation unit', where its type specifies what unit to align to. I guess that opens the question of why it needs a type, when the following non-zero-sized bitfield has one, but you might need a time machine to ask the Committee that

Comment: This should be marked as the correct solution. All the other answers can be optimized away, whereas using a bitfield is guaranteed.

Comment: I don't think this can be used to define an enum that can be used outside a struct, correct?

Comment: No. Only inside a `struct` as it is a property of the bitset syntax.

Comment: C11 6.7.2.1p5 says that _A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type_, which means that your answer only works if the implementation allows enum as a bit-field type. C11 6.7.2.1p11 says that _An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field_, it does not have to be a multiple of the underlying type (which I had assumed before).

Answer (score 12):

In some circumstances, this may be helpful:

```
typedef uint8_t command_t;
enum command_enum
{
    CMD_IDENT                = 0x00,     //!< Identify command
    CMD_SCENE_0              = 0x10,     //!< Recall Scene 0 command
    CMD_SCENE_1              = 0x11,     //!< Recall Scene 1 command
    CMD_SCENE_2              = 0x12,     //!< Recall Scene 2 command
};

/* cmdVariable is of size 8 */
command_t cmdVariable = CMD_IDENT;
```

On one hand type `command_t` has size 1 (8bits) and can be used for variable and function parameter type.
On the other hand you can use the enum values for assignation that are of type `int` by default but the compiler will cast them immediately when assigned to a `command_t` type variable.

Also, if you do something unsafe like defining and using a `CMD_16bit = 0xFFFF,` the compiler will warn you with following message:

> warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

**Edit:** If and you are searching for this topic, maybe it's time to start searching for C++ usage in embedded and switching some of your code to C++ and use [class enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: "the compiler" refers to GCC here, other compilers may or may not issue this or a similar warning.

Comment: Actually, this is going to be of size *1*, because [sizeof(uint8_t) == 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655355/294313) where it exists at all. It's 8 bits, though.

Answer (score 10):

You can force it to be at least a certain size by defining an appropriate value.  For example, if you want your enum to be stored as the same size as an `int`, even though all the values would fit in a `char`, you can do something like this:

```
typedef enum {
    firstValue = 1,
    secondValue = 2,

    Internal_ForceMyEnumIntSize = MAX_INT
} MyEnum;
```

Note, however, that the behavior can be dependent on the implementation.

As you note, passing such a value to a function will cause it to be expanded to an int anyway, but if you are using your type in an array or a struct, then the size will matter.  If you really care about element sizes, you should really use types like `int8_t`, `int32_t`, etc.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought. I tend to have a number of enums defined that really don't need more than 8 or 16 bits, and I hate wasting space when I don't have to.

Comment: This might not work if the optimizer removes your unused `Internal_ForceMyEnumIntSize`

Comment: @KJohnson Is Internal_ForceMyEnumIntSize is C keyword?

Comment: @Patrick No, it's just another member of the enum. It could have been called thirdValue, or lastValue, or maxValue. MAX_INT is defined by C to be the maximum int value.

Comment: @EBlake C99 [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366033/2757035) that the type "shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration." It says nothing about permitting an optimiser to remove members, so I can't see how that'd be allowed. Nor can I see what would be the point of doing it? What is there to gain? Enumerators are just alternative ways to name integral constants; if an enumerator member is not used in the code, surely it can't appear in the binary so there is nothing to remove, nothing to optimise.

Comment: In default case, enum are always stored as int so the example is not very relevant. Also, using 0xFF instead of MAX_INT will not give an 8 bit enum size but "at least 8 bit" like you explained. And by default in GCC this will be a 32 bit int.

Comment: @EBlake Can you please provide an example of a compiler that legitimately optimized this case? Otherwise, please remove your comment as it contradicts C99; furthermore it would be a pain if the size of an enum type depended upon the values that are actually used in each of the translation units. Each translation unit would then get its own different size, which is simply unmanageable.

Answer (score 5):

As @Nyx0uf [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879350/4561887), GCC has a flag which you can set:

> `-fshort-enums`
>
> Allocate to an enum type only as many bytes as it needs for the declared range of possible values. Specifically, the enum type is equivalent to the smallest integer type that has enough room.
>
> Warning: the `-fshort-enums` switch causes GCC to generate code that is not binary compatible with code generated without that switch. Use it to conform to a non-default application binary interface.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

**Additional great reading for general insight:** https://www.embedded.fm/blog/2016/6/28/how-big-is-an-enum.
Interesting...notice the line I highlighted in yellow below! Adding an enum entry called `ARM_EXCEPTION_MAKE_ENUM_32_BIT` and with a value equal to `0xffffffff`, which is the equivalent of `UINT32_MAX` from `stdint.h` (see [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)), forces this particular `Arm_symbolic_exception_name` enum to have an integer type of `uint32_t`. That is the sole purpose of this `ARM_EXCEPTION_MAKE_ENUM_32_BIT` entry! *It works because `uint32_t` is the smallest integer type which can contain all of the enum values in this enum--namely: `0` through `8`, inclusive, as well as `0xffffffff`, or decimal `2^32-1` = `4294967295`.*

[image]

<sub>Keywords: ARM_EXCEPTION_MAKE_ENUM_32_BIT enum purpose why have it? Arm_symbolic_exception_name purpose of 0xffffffff enum entry at end.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Right now I can't answer your first two questions, because I am trying to find a good way to do this myself. Maybe I will edit this if I find a strategy that I like. It isn't intuitive though.

But I want to point something out that hasn't been mentioned so far, and to do so I will answer the third question like so:

**It is "worth doing" when writing a C API that will be called from languages that aren't C**. Anything that directly links to the C code will need to correctly understand the memory layout of all structs, parameter lists, etc in the C code's API. Unfortunately, C types like `int`, or worst yet, enums, are fairly unpredictably sized (changes by compiler, platform, etc), so knowing the memory layout of anything containing an enum can be dodgy unless your other programming language's compiler is also the C compiler AND it has some in-language mechanism to exploit that knowledge. It is much easier to write problem-free bindings to C libraries when the API uses predictably-sized C types like `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, `void*`, `uintptr_t`, etc, and structs/unions composed of those predictably-sized types.

So I would care about enum sizing when it matters for program correctness, such as when memory layout and alignment issues are possible. But I wouldn't worry about it so much for optimization, not unless you have some niche situation that amplifies the opportunity cost (ex: a large array/list of enum-typed values on a memory constrained system like a small MCU).

Unfortunately, situations like what I'm mentioning are not helped by something like `-fshort-enums`, because this feature is vendor-specific and *less* predictable (e.g. another system would have to "guess" enum size by approximating GCC's algorithm for `-fshort-enums` enum sizing). If anything, it would allow people to compile C code in a way that would break common assumptions made by bindings in other languages (or other C code that wasn't compiled with the same option), with the expected result being memory corruption as parameters or struct members get written to, or read from, the wrong locations in memory.

Comment: It irks me that the Standard seems hostile to the notion of code which needs to abide constraints outside the C implementation's control.  Even something as simple as recognizing a category of implementations which use the commonplace struct layout algorithm of putting each memory at the lowest offset which follows all previous objects and fits its alignment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the values assigned for the enums.

Ex:
If the value greater than 2^32-1 is stored, the size allocated for the overall enum will change to the next size.

Store 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF value to a enum variable, it will give warning if tried to compile in a 32 bit environment (round off warning)
Where as in a 64 bit compilation, it will be successful and the size allocated will be 8 bytes.

Comment: I tried this in clang 11 and the compiler just truncated the value to 32 bits.