# How to set the value of an enumeration constant outside the range of int?

Tags: c, enums, enumeration, c99, language-lawyer

The C99 standard requires that the expression used to define the value of an enumeration constant has a value representable as an `int`.

In **section 6.7.2.2** paragraph 2 of the C99 standard:

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer
>   constant expression that has a value representable as an **`int`**.

However, enumerated types can be defined by the implementation to be compatible with any integer type, including those with a range of values outside of `int`.

In **section 6.7.2.2** paragraph 2 of the C99 standard:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with **`char`**, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type.

This means that while you cannot explicitly set the value of an enumeration constant outside the range of an `int`, the value of an enumeration constant can be outside the range of an `int` if the implementation defines the enumeration type to be compatible with an integer type with a range outside of `int`.

---

Now I know one way to get a specific value outside the range of `int` set for an enumeration constant: *dummy enumerators*.

```
enum hack{
    DUMMY0 = INT_MAX,
    DUMMY1,
    /* supply as many more dummy enumerators as needed */
    ...
    /* declare desired enumerator */
    FOOBAR
};
```

This works thanks to **section 6.7.2.2** paragraph 3 of the C99 standard:

> An enumerator with `=` defines its
>   enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression.
>   ...
>   Each subsequent enumerator with no `=`
>   defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by
>   adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.

Unfortunately, this only works for **positive** values greater than `INT_MAX`, since the value of each subsequent enumerator is only ever incremented. Another caveat is the need to create possibly many *dummy enumerators* just to acquire the specific enumerator desired.

---

This leads to the following questions:

1. Is there a way to set the value of an enumeration constant to a **negative** value outside the range of `int`?
2. Is there a better way to set a **positive** value outside the range of `int` to an enumeration constant?
3. Regarding my *dummy enumerator* hack, does the C99 standard set a limit on the number of enumerators which may be declared in a single `enum`?

Comment: No you can't. What you can do however, is to implement your own enumeration-function that uses big numbers. But I honestly don't know why you would do that.

Comment: @Jocke What would an implementation of an enumeration-function look like?

Comment: What happens when you create more than 2^32 enums?

Comment: You cant implement it as syntax of course. But as a function it could be done with a hash table that you populate with these big numbers with the key as a string of your own choosing.

Comment: as far as I can tell, using dummy enumerators doesn't help here - *adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant* should result in a signed integer overflow; however, your compiler might support promoting enumerations to larger integer types as a non-standard extension...

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879286/specifying-size-of-enum-type-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **How to set the value of an enumeration constant outside the range of int?**

You don't. (For now, but see **UPDATE 2** below if you're using a C23 or later compiler.)

> The C99 standard requires that the expression used to define the value
> of an enumeration constant has a value representable as an `int`.

Yes, and the C11 standard didn't change any of this.

> However, enumerated types can be defined by the implementation to be
> compatible with any integer type, including those with a range of
> values outside of `int`.

Also correct.

> This means that while you cannot explicitly set the value of an
> enumeration constant outside the range of an `int`, the value of an
> enumeration constant can be outside the range of an `int` if the
> implementation defines the enumeration type to be compatible with an
> integer type with a range outside of `int`.

That's incorrect, but I think you've found a weakness in the wording in the standard. (Update: I don't think it's really a weakness; see below). You quoted 6.7.2.2:

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall
> be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an
> **int**.

which seems to apply only when the value is defined by an *explicit* expression, not to a case like this:

```
enum too_big {
    big = INT_MAX,
    even_bigger
};
```

But this doesn't actually work, since `even_bigger` is declared as a constant of type `int`, which clearly cannot have the value `INT_MAX + 1`.

I strongly suspect that the *intent* is that the above declaration is illegal (a constraint violation); probably 6.7.2.2 should be reworded to make that clearer. (Update: I now think it's clear enough; see below.)

The authors of gcc seem to agree with me:

```
$ cat c.c
#include <limits.h>
enum huge {
    big = INT_MAX,
    even_bigger
};
$ gcc -c c.c
c.c:4:5: error: overflow in enumeration values
```

so even if your interpretation is correct, you're not likely to be able to write and use code that depends on it.

A workaround is to use integers (enumeration types are more or less thinly disguised integers anyway).  A `const` integer object isn't a constant expression, unfortunately, so you might have to resort to using the preprocessor:

```
typedef long long huge_t;
#define big ((huge_t)INT_MAX)
#define even_bigger (big + 1)
```

This assumes that `long long` is wider than `int`, which is likely but not guaranteed (`int` and `long long` could be the same size if `int` is at least 64 bits).

The answer to your questions 1 and 2 is no; you can't define an enumeration constant, *either negative or positive*, outside the range of `int`.

As for your question 3, section 5.2.4.1 of the C11 standard says (roughly) that a compiler must support *at least* 1023 enumeration constants in a single enumeration. Most compilers don't actually impose a fixed limit, but in any case all of the constants must have values within the range `INT_MIN` .. `INT_MAX`, so that doesn't do you much good. (Multiple enumeration constants in the same type can have the same value.)

(The translation limit requirement is actually more complicated than that. A compiler must support *at least one* program that contains at least one instance of all of an enumerated list of limits. That's a fairly useless requirement as stated. The intent is that the easiest way to meet the requirement given by the Standard is to avoid imposing any fixed limits.)

**UPDATE :**

I raised this issue on the comp.std.c Usenet newsgroup. Tim Rentsch raised a good point in that discussion, and I now think that this:

```
enum too_big {
    big = INT_MAX,
    even_bigger
};
```

is a constraint violation, requiring a compiler diagnostic.

My concern was that the wording that forbids an *explicit* value outside the range of `int`:

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall
> be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an
> **int**.

does not apply, since there is no (explicit) *expression* involved. But 6.7.7.2p3 says:

> Each subsequent enumerator with no **=** defines its enumeration
> constant as the value of the constant **expression** obtained by adding 1
> to the value of the previous enumeration constant.

(emphasis added).  So there is an *expression* whose value must be representable as an `int`; it just doesn't appear in the source. I'm not 100% comfortable with that, but I'd say the intent is sufficiently clear.

Here's the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/fkEI_wcnoJ4) on comp.std.c.

**UPDATE 2:**

The 2023 edition of the ISO C standard (not yet published as I write this, but the latest draft is [N3054](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf)) allows an *enum-type-specifier* to specify the underlying type of an enumeration type.

gcc 13.1.0 has partial support for C23 with the `-std=c2x` option.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) {
    enum small { zero, one };
    enum big : long long { BIG = UINT_MAX + 1LL, BIGGER };
    printf("%d %d %lld %lld\n", zero, one, BIG, BIGGER);
}
```

The output with gcc 13.1.0 on my system is:

```
0 1 4294967296 4294967297
```

Comment: Is section **6.7.2.2** paragraph 3 (`The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.`) where enumeration constants are required to be of type `int` and thus the reason why `even_bigger` would be invalid? If so, is there a specific reason why the word "*identifiers*" was used instead of "*enumerators*", or was this simply just the author's word choice of preference?

Comment: Because identifiers is what they are.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I cannot say anything that Keith Thompson has not told you, yet.
I'll do my try, anyway.

**1. Values in the range of int**

In the document of **ISO C99**, I can see in section **6.7.2.2**, paragraphs 2 and 3, the following statements:

> (2) The expression that deﬁnes the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer
>   constant expression that has a value representable as an int.

If you write `enum T { X = (expr) } VAR`, then `expr` is an integer number in the range of an **int**, which includes, at least, the range *-32767 .. +32767*, as you can read in `5.2.4.2.1`.
Of course, the paragraph **(2)** does not imposes any restriction on the type of the identifier *X*.

**2. Enumerator identifiers have type int**

In paragraph **3** we can read this line:

> (3a) The identiﬁers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.

This is a restriction on the type of the identifier. Now *X* has type **int**.

**3. Discussion about the values**

Also, the standard says:

> (3b) An enumerator with = deﬁnes its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression.

But this sentence, now, is restricted by **(2)** and **(3a)**.
So, my interpretation of the standard C99 is as follows:
If you write

```
 enum T { X = INT_MAX, BIGG}
```

then `BIGG` has type **int** (according to **(3a)**).
As Keith Tompson pointed out, the value (=*"enumerator constant?"*) of **BIGG** is not coming from an *expression*, representing an out-of-range value (for **int**). Its value  (in mathematical sense) is *X+1*, because the next rule is applied:

> (3c) Each subsequent enumerator with no =
>   deﬁnes its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by
>   adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.

There is not any rule in the standard (about integer arithmetic) that defines the behaviour of the compiler in this case. So, it would fall in the `implementation defined` class...
However, in the case that the compiler accepts this out-of-range value, I believe that the (mathematical) *X+1* will be converted to a value in the **int** range.

But, the intended behaviour in **(3b)** seems to be that the **C** expression **(X+1) == BIGG** is always **true**.
If I am right, then I am agreeing with Keith, and the compiler has to reject the declaration with an **Out of range** error.

**4. The integer type of enumerated types**

We can read this even more:

> (4a) Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type.

The declaration `enum T` defines a new **integer type**.
This type is not neccesarilly related to the type of *expression* `expr`,
neither to the type of *enumerator* `X`.
It is just another type for another thing: the integer type associated to the **enum** type `T` we are defining.
(This type will be the one assigned to the variable `VAR_T`).

The implementation can decide what integer type is the more appropiated.
If the expressions (like `expr`) have very small values, as almost always happens,
then the compiler may decide that `T` is of type **char**, for example.
If a **long long** is desired for some reason,
then the type of `T` will be **long long**, and so on.

However, this does not change the restrictions to **int** that the expression `expr` and the enumerator `X` have to follow. They are **int**.
The only rule that relates the types of `expr` and `T` is:

> (4b) The choice of type is implementation-deﬁned, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.

Thus, if you have `enum T { X = 0, Y = 5, Z = 9 }`, then the type of `T` is able to be a **char**.
(The situation is analogous to the case that a character constant, like `'c'`, which always has type **int**, is passed to a **char** variable: `char c = 'c';`: although `'c'` is an **int**, its value fits in the range of a **char**).

On the other hand, if you have `enum T { X = 20202, Y = -3 }`, the compiler cannot choose **char** for `T`. It seems that **int** is the perfect type for `T` (as for any **enum** type), but the compiler can choose any other integer type for `T` whose range contains the values *20202* and *-3*.

If none value is negative, then the compiler could choose an `unsigned` integer type.

**5. Summary**

In summary, we can say that:

1. There are **4** types involved in an **enum** declaration: for the expressions (`expr`), the values (or enumeration constants, coming from expressions or just implicit), the enumerators (`X`), and the **enum** type (`T`).
2. The type of expressions (as `expr`) is always **int**. The type of the values seems hardly intended to be in the range of an **int** (`INT_MAX+1` seems to be not allowed). The type of the enumerators is **int** (as `X`). And the **enum** types (as `T`) are chosen by the implementation, among the all possible integer types allowed, just fitting the values inside the declaration.
3. In expressions, we have that:

   `#define NN 5`
   `enum T { X = 0. Y = 3, Z = (NN*3) } evar;`

The expression `(NN * 3) + 1` is an **int**.
The expression `(Z + 1)` is an **int**.
If the compiler defines `T` as a **char**,
then the expression `((evar = Z), ++evar)` is a **char**.

Answer (score 2):

The standard says `...the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value...`.
Thus, a non-explicit expression "value" is considered as coming from a **constant expression**, too.

However, to ensure that only **int** "values" are allowed, one has to consider, jointly, the restriction that paragraph 2 declares: `The expression that deﬁnes the value of an enumeration constant ... has a value representable as an int`.
Thus, the (non-explicit expression) values also have to fit in an **int**.

I am convinced now that the intended constraint is that every enumerator value fits in an `int`.