# can I assume that sizeof(uint8_t) = 1?

Tags: c, sizeof, uint8t, uint

I have a program that uses dynamic allocation for a uint8_t array; can I safely 
assume that its length will always be one byte?

Comment: Theoretically, no. You can't even assume `uint8_t` *exists*, even in a C99-compliant environment. Practically speaking, however, yeah it's pretty safe on anything even remotely modern.

Comment: In practice, yes. I challenge you to find a modern architecture where this is not true.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: It's not exactly modern, but some of the old-school Crays were "everything data type is 64 bits". I don't recall how they handled character data though, might have cheated a bit. They might have lasted long enough to develop C99 compilers.

Comment: Why not use `sizeof (uint8_t)` and not worry about implementation details?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8

Comment: @nemequ: If it exists it must be 1.

Comment: It seems a safe assumption, but why?  In general, code is more robust when you minimize the number of assumptions.  If you need the size of a uint8_t, why not just write sizeof(uint8_t)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If `uint8_t` exists, then `sizeof(uint8_t)` must be 1. `uint8_t` is [required](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1) to have width exactly 8 and no padding bits, and [`CHAR_BIT`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) is required to be at least 8. If `uint8_t` exists, it can't have more than one char's worth of bits without violating these requirements.