Why use macro definitions in enumerations? Rather than being all members of enumeration types?
Original writing
enum fdb_sector_store_status {
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_UNUSED,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_EMPTY,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_USING,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_FULL,
#define FDB_SECTOR_STORE_STATUS_NUM              4
};

I saw an open source code. Why are macro definitions used to describe the number of enumerations instead of writing it directly?
enum fdb_sector_store_status {
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_UNUSED,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_EMPTY,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_USING,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_FULL,
    FDB_SECTOR_STORE_STATUS_NUM,
};

URL: https: //github.com/armink/FlashDB
In order to reduce the type cast operation during the for loop?

There's no obvious reason. Maybe they wanted to use one particular constant in a pre-processor expression and cooked up a dirty hack to make that possible?

@Lundin The #define method does result in a constant for the number of elements that's not a member of the enumerated type.  Maybe they're using a code analysis tool that does things like check that switch constructs have a case statement for every value in the enum?

I took a closer look at Github and it's not pretty. The person who wrote it simply has a habit of spewing out #define in the middle of the code for no apparent reason, like #define BUF_SIZE 32 in the middle of a function. Now there are cases where you might want to write #define in the middle of the code (to indicate it's just some local thing, despite it sitting in the global namespace regardless) but this isn't one. They should use const variables etc instead.

@AndrewHenle In that case the correct fix is to add a default: with something like an empty ; line etc. Or error handling, in case the code isn't supposed to go there (aka "defensive programming").

Well, one reason could be that the type of the define is int, while when it is a member of enum it will be of type of that enum. Which might produce warnings when used as int later in the code. Also the encoding of enum is generally implementation specific and not necessarily int.

@EugeneSh. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.3p2

@n.m.couldbeanAI Right.. I guess it is just a common extension I was thinking about... also looks like in C23 as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879286/specifying-size-of-enum-type-in-c

@EugeneSh. An enumeration constant (FDB_SECTOR_STORE_UNUSED etc) is always of type int, same thing with an integer constant/"literal" like 4. The enumerated type itself could be smaller than int though, in case the compiler likes that - it is of an implementation-defined size. C23 attempts to get rid of the enum type madness by allowing one to specify a type like enum stuff : uint32_t. Most enums are after all effectively unsigned.

An enumeration constant (FDB_SECTOR_STORE_UNUSED etc) is always of type int - That's a really interesting distinction I was not aware of, and I am not sure of the implications of it.. but it seems to be true: https://godbolt.org/z/P1rfazK4b

Edit: example modified to avoid misunderstanding
Adding the number of status as another enum value has one disadvantage. If you use the enum in switch / case statements without default you might get a warning, like in this not very meaningful example
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum example {
        ZERO,
        ONE,
        COUNT   
};

int     main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        enum example    ex = ZERO;

        if( argc > 1 ) {
                int     n = atoi( argv[1] );
                if( n < 0 || n >= COUNT ) {
                        printf( "%s: invalid value\n", argv[1] );
                } else {
                        ex = n;
                }
        }
        switch( ex ) {
        case ZERO:
                printf( "ZERO\n" );
                break;
        case ONE:
                printf( "ONE\n" );
                break;
        }
        return 0;
}

Compiling with gcc -Wall gives
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:22:9: warning: enumeration value ‘COUNT’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
   22 |         switch( ex ) {

Using a #define for the number of values instead can solve that

Notably it is the wrong solution for that diagnostic message though. The correct solution is to add a default, not to deface the enum. And the cause of the warning to begin with is the questionable cast in the switch(). Enumeration constants are guaranteed to be of type int and the switch() condition is implicitly integer promoted. (Assuming pre-C23 enums.)

@Lundin regarding the cast: the only reason for this exampe is to provoque the warning. Of course the cast doesn't make sense as the whole program doesn't. But I disagree with the statement that adding default is always the right solution. The enum in the question is a list of status and if I have a swiitch() which shall execute something for every status I won't have a default and adding it silences a warning that is welcome if I forgot one status.

Well adding a default is one acceptable fix by MISRA C and similar coding standards, same deal as ending every else if with else. Preferable to the alternative which is run-away code. Now if you want to be super clear about it, you could write case COUNT: default: and there could be no misunderstanding. Maybe that's the best solution.

Either way, #define is the wrong solution to the wrong problem.

@IngoLeonhardt But I disagree with the statement that adding default is always the right solution. enum isn't type-safe - any numeric value can be converted to an enum.  In the (current) code you've posted simply starting the process with more command-line arguments will "break" the switch.  So there's always the possibility of an improper value.

@Andrew Henle as I've already written I'm very aware of that and the example code makes no sense other than provoquing the warning. But I have already experienced circumstances where you can be reasonably sure that an enum will never have an invalid value and in such cases adding default would silence a welcome diacnostic
