# Heap corruption on free(...)

Tags: c++, free, heap-corruption

I have this *enum* type:

```
enum Cell { ALIVE='X', DEAD='O' };
```

And I allocate an array with it:

```
h_board = (Cell*) malloc(width*height*sizeof(char));
```

I assume I'm not doing this wrong since *Cell* values are chars (I'd like to stay with char sized data but I care for readability, that's why I used the *enum*.)

Upon `free(h_board);` an exception is thrown. In debugging mode I can see a heap corruption warning. I guess I'm freeing more memory than I'm allocating, but I can't see why. I also tried `free((char*)h_board);` trying to enforce char size deallocation, but the problem persists.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're overwriting something somewhere. Show some code ?

Comment: What is the type of h_board ? I assume it's `Cell*`. What does Valgrind tell you ? Could you put the minimal code needed to recreate this problem and show us what happens to h_board ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong yet, but you'd better use `sizeof(Cell)` instead of `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: Cell values are not chars they are ints, better to use `sizeof(Cell)`

Comment: @cnicutar @Eregrith The minimal code is pretty much that. Define `h_board` as `Cell*`, put it in a `main()` and it runs.

Comment: @Naveen I see, I thought definining them as 'char' made them chars. Can't I enforce enum's size to char? I guess not and the int is just an index, am I right?

Comment: Just because the `enum` values are `char` doesn't mean `sizeof(Cell) == sizeof(char)`: it's not.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? Even if I'm wrong, it's still a valid question... (if I were right I wouldn't ask!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `Cell` is it's own datatype (which doesn't necessarily map to `char`), so use malloc with that (plus, we don't cast `malloc` in C):

```
Cell *h_board = malloc(width * height * sizeof(Cell));
```

Second, we need the full code to be able to help you accurately. This should run without any errors, perhaps you can build from here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Cell *h_board;

    h_board = malloc(20 * 30 * sizeof(*h_board));
    free(h_board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I need to post more code, that's all I needed. Thanks. I just wanted to enforce char size for enum... but I guess I just can't.

Comment: kaoD: the whole purpose of an enum is to make type-safe easy numerical constants that will have good performance. It's more than logical that the compiler chooses `int`, because that is usually the word-size on implementations, and word-size is the fastest to process for the CPU. If you want constants with the type `char` you can still write `const char ALIVE = 'x';`, etc.

Comment: By the way, not casting to `Cell*` won't work. To be honest, I'm not sure if this is C or C++ (I'm progamming for CUDA) but I need to cast it.

Comment: @kaoD: then you are writing C++, but you tagged your question C.

Comment: @kaoD: in C++ you can use `new[]` and `delete[]` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be sizeof(Cell). Making any assumptions about the size of the enum can be dangerous.
Just for your reference : [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)