# Using integer as an enumeration value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {AA, BB, CC} s;

int main()
{
s = 4;
printf("%d\n",s);
return 0;
}
```

The compiler doesn't give any warning and prints 4. What is happening behind the scene? Is `s` treated as an `int` type?

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific type of an enumeration is implementation specific, but it is often an `int`.  So yes, in this case `s` is probably an `int`.  From the C spec:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with **`char`**, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. The enumerated type is incomplete until after the **`}`** that terminates the list of enumerator declarations.

So in your case, 4 will certainly work, since it fits in a `char` and in any signed or unsigned integer type on any machine I've ever heard of.

Comment: How can I find the specific type. I am using gcc.

Comment: Check the gcc documentation, I guess.  You could use `sizeof` to get a baseline.

Comment: I had another idea - you could deliberately make a `printf` format mismatch with your `s` variable - gcc will print a warning that includes the type name, I think.

Comment: Nice! test.c:8: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'unsigned int'