# C language enumeration datatype?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)

Regrading the C language enumerations: users have no control over size of enumeration variables. Can someone explain this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c

Comment: You do have control in the sense that the enum will have a datatype large enough to fit your biggest number in. what else you need to know about it?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is from C99 6.7.2.2p4

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,<sup>108</sup>) but shall be
>   capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.
>
> 108) An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have
>   been seen.

This allows the compiler to make what it believes to be the best choice for a particular enumeration. An enumeration is probably not the best choice to use in a binary message passed between machines. But, you can use an integer type, and cast back to the enumerated type.