# Enum bitwise masking limitations

Tags: objective-c, c, enums

I was trying to enumerate filetypes with bitmasking for fast and easy distinguishing on bitwise OR:

```
typedef enum {

    FileTypeDirectory = 1,
    FileTypePIX = 2,
    FileTypeJPG = 4,
    FileTypePNG = 8,
    FileTypeGIF = 16,
    FileTypeHTML = 32,
    FileTypeXML = 64,
    FileTypeTXT = 128,
    FileTypePDF = 256,  
    FileTypePPTX = 512,

    FileTypeAll = 1023

} FileType;
```

My OR operations did work until 128, afterwards it failed. Are enums on a 64 Bit Mac OSX limited to Byte Datatypes? (2^7=128)

Comment: See [this old SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/366026/440558).

Comment: The enum from your code is guaranteed to be large enough to hold `1023`, so the problem most likely has something to do with your "afterwards it failed" check.

Comment: Hmmm....might be useful to post the code where the OR'ing is failing....

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the answer there is misleading, I think, because it speaks about the storage size of objects of the enumeration type and not of the constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `enum` *constants* in C are of type `int` and not of the type of the enumeration itself. So the restriction is not in the storage size for `enum` variables, but only in the number of bits for an `int`.

I don't know much of objective-c (as this is tagged also) but it shouldn't deviate much from C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you used the `OR` operator but it works for me well with your `typedef`.

```
FileType _fileType = FileTypeGIF | FileTypePDF | FileTypePPTX;
NSLog(@"filetype is : %d", _fileType);
```

the result is:

```
filetype is : 784
```

which is correct values  because `16 + 256 + 512` is precisely `784`.

---

(it has been **tested on real device** only.)

Comment: I tested it too and saw that the failure has to be somewhere else. the enumerations works properly!

Comment: @LowNoise, then how did you experience, as you've mentioned, _My OR operations did work until 128, afterwards it failed_?

Comment: It actually occured somewhere else, my mentioning was not correct.