# How does Enum allocate Memory on C?

Tags: c, assembly, enums, abi

I'm trying to work with C and Assembly (intelx8086) language.

I'm also using one class that was implemented by a friend of mine. It has a

```
typedef enum data_10 {a=0,b=7,c=10,} data_10_type;
```

I want to work with this class bitwise (AKA construct it/destroy it on Assembly). My question is, how much memory does "enum" take?

Comment: In C, same as an `int`. In C++0x, it can be more or less based on the base type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size of an enum in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) has some information relevant to your task.

Comment: C doesn't have classes, at least not as a first-class language feature.  Maybe you mean a struct with a member of that `data_10_type` type?

Answer (score 6):

Although it may vary from compiler to compiler, `enum` typically takes the same size as an `int`.  To be sure, though, you can always use `sizeof( data_10_type );`

Comment: This will tell you the size on one particular version of one compiler on one architecture.  It's not future-proof.

Comment: @NovaDenizen Only if you print it out once and use that forever. Better to store it in a variable and use that to do the allocation.

Comment: @Greyson So the OP is writing in assembly, but in every single reference to these structures he does address arithmetic based on this variable?  It seems more probable to me that OP wants to know definitively the byte layout of the fields in the structure, but this information doesn't exist outside the context of a single version of a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you print it?

```
/* C99 */
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { a = 0, b = 7, c = 10 } data_10_type;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(data_10_type));
```

The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int` (**C11 §6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**), so `sizeof(data_10_type)` is often equal to `sizeof(int)`, but it isn't necessary!

BTW, if you want to have a size in bits, just use the `CHAR_BIT` constant (defined in `<limits.h>`), which indicates how many bits there are in a single byte).

```
/* C99 */
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { a = 0, b = 7, c = 10 } data_10_type;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(data_10_type) * CHAR_BIT);
```

Comment: in which cases does CHAR_BIT differ from 8?

Comment: The standard says `CHAR_BIT` is greater than 8. For example, on DSPs, `CHAR_BIT` is often equal to 16.

Comment: @Dirk: there's no guarantee that CHAR_BIT will be 8.  Historically, bytes have been 6, 7, and 8 bits.  Modern embedded systems may have different sizes of char (16-bits, for example).  We also don't know what architectures will look like 10+ years down the road, so it's best not to assume (or to at least use static assertions to fail safely).

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` must be *at least* 8; it may be larger, but not smaller (5.2.4.2.1, "implementation-deﬁned values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign").

Answer (score 1):

An enum does not really take any memory at all; it's understood by the compiler and the right numbers get used during compilation. It's an int, whose size is dependent on your system.