# How to convert a complex data type from host byte order to network order

Tags: c

I want to translate a message from host byte order to network order using htonl() and htos(). In this message, there are some complex defined data type slike structure, enum, union and union in union.

1. Shall I have to htonl(s) on every structure's members, and members in member, including the union's member that are multi-byte?
2. For an union, can I just translate the largest one?
3. For enum, can I just translate it just as a long?
4. Can I just write one function that is using htonl(s) for both sending and receiving message? Or do I have to come up with another one that is using ntohl(s) for receiving the same message?

#### Structures

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short un1_s;
    unsigned char  un1_c;

    union {
        unsigned short un1_u_s;        
        unsigned long  un1_u_l;    
    }u;
}UN1;

typedef struct {
    unsigned short    un2_s1;
    unsigned short    un2_s2;
} UN2;

typedef enum {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    TRHEE,
    FOUR
} ENUM_ID;

typedef struct {
    unsigned short  s_sid;
    unsigned int    i_sid;
    unsigned char   u_char;
    ENUM_ID         i_enum;

    union {
            UN1     un1;
            UN2     un2;
    }               u;
} MSG;
```

#### Code

```
void msgTranslate (MSG* in_msg, MSG* out_msg){

/* ignore the code validating pointer ... */

*out_msg = *in_msg;

#ifdef LITLE_ENDIAN

/* translating messeage */
out_msg->s_sid = htons( in_msg->s_sid );  /* short */
out_msg->i_sid = htonl( in_msg->i_sid );  /* int */

/* Can I simply leave out_msg->u_char not to translate, 
 * because it is a single byte? */

out_msg->i_enum = htonl(in_msg->i_enum);  
/* Can I simply translate a enum this way,? */

/* For an union whose 1st member is largest one in size than 
 * others, can I just translate the 1st one, 
 * leaving the others not to convert? */

out_msg->u.un1.un1_s = htons(in_msg->u.un1.un1_s);  


/* for out_msg->u_char, can I simply leave it 
 * not to be converted, because it is a single byte? */

/* for an union whose 2nd member is largest one, 
 * can I just convert the 2nd one, leaving others 
 * not to be converted? */

out_msg->u.un1.u.un1_u_s = htos(in_msg->u.un1.u.un1_u_s ); /* short */

/* As above question, the following line can be removed? 
 * just because the u.un1.u.un2_u_i is smaller 
 * than u.un1.u.un1 in size ? */

out_msg->u.un1.u.un2_u_i = htol(in_msg->u.un1.u.un2_u_l );  /* long */

/* Since un1 is largest than un2, the coding translation un2 can be ignored? */
    ...

#endif

    return;
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Padding/packing is going to be murderous with this scheme...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You will need to map every multi-byte type appropriately.
2. For a union, you need to identify which is the 'active' element of the union, and map that according to the normal rules.  You may also need to provide a 'discriminator' which tells the receiving code which of the various possibilities was transmitted.
3. For enum, you could decide that all such values will be treated as a `long` and encode and decode accordingly.  Alternatively, you can deal with each enum separately, handling each type according to its size (where, in theory, different enums could have different sizes).
4. It depends a bit on what you're really going to do next.  If you're packaging data for transmission over the network, then the receive and the send operations are rather different.  If all you're doing is flipping bits in a structure in memory, then you will probably find that on most systems, the results of applying the `htonl()` function to the result of `htonl()` is the number you first thought of.  If you're planning to do a binary copy of all the bytes in the mapped (flipped) structure, you're probably not doing it right.

Note that your data structures have various padding holes in them on most plausible systems.  In structure UN1, you almost certainly have a padding byte between `un1_c` and the following union `u`, if it is a 32-bit system; you'd probably have 5 bytes padding there if it is a 64-bit system.  Similarly, in the `MSG` structure, you have probably got 2 padding bytes after `s_sid`, and 3 more after `u_char`.  Depending on the size of the `enum` (and whether you're on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine), you might have 1-7 bytes of padding after `i_enum`.

Note that because you do not have platform independent sizes for the data types, you cannot reliably interwork between 32-bit and 64-bit Unix systems.  If the systems are all Windows, then you get away with it since `sizeof(long) == 4` on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.  However, on essentially all 64-bit variants of Unix, `sizeof(long) == 8`.  So, if working cross-platform is an issue, you have to worry about those sizes as well as the padding.  Investigate the types in the `<inttypes.h>` header such as `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`.

You should simply do the same packing on all hosts, carefully copying the bytes of the various values into the appropriate place in a character buffer, which is then sent over the wire and unpacked by the inverse coding.

Also check out whether Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) would do the job for you sensibly; it might save you a fair amount of pain and grief.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and pointing out potential issues. I have decide to use a field to indicate which union member is using, then future convert the specific member in case.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to endian-flip any integer that is longer than 1 byte (short, int, long, long long).
2. No. See below.
3. No. `enum` might be any size, depending on your platform (see [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)).
4. Realistically, you should just use Protocol Buffers or something instead of trying to do all of this conversion...

Unions are hard to handle. Say, for instance, I store the value 0x1234 in the `short` of a `union {short; long;}` in big-endian. Then, the union contains the bytes `12 34 00 00`, since the short occupies the low two bytes of the union. If you endian-flip the `long`, you get `00 00 34 12`, which produces the `short` 0x0000. If you endian-flip the `short`, you get `34 12 00 00`. I'm not sure which one you would consider correct, but it's pretty clear that you have a problem.

It's more typical to have two `short`s in a union like that, with one `short` being the low halfword and the other short being the high halfword. Which one is which depends on endianness, but you can do

```
union {
    #ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
    uint16_t s_lo, s_hi;
    #else
    uint16_t s_hi, s_lo;
    #endif
    uint32_t l;
};
```

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for you quick and clear response. I get to understand why I can't convert the union simply by converting the largest one in size. I learned a lot from you post.