# Howto serialize and deserialize between unknown typedef struct and QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

I am an absolute beginner to C++ and Qt.

I am broadcasting different data via TCP using Qt. The process of sending and retrieving data works fine but I have problems on interpreting the data on the receivers side.

The data is represented in different structs which have in common that they have a `commandId` and a state. The rest could be anything like an error message, a filename or something else. This code is not written on my own and I am not allowed to change it (e.g: define and implement a common interfaces.)

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t commandId;
  State state;
  //special data
  QString errorMessage;
} Command1;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t commandId;
  State state;
  //special data
  uint8_t amountSensors;
} Command2;

enum State {
  STATID_PAUSE = 50000
  STATID_RECORD = 50001
  STATID_PLAY = 50002
  STATID_ERROR = 50003
}
```

The sender is converting a struct into a `QByteArray` this way:

```
Command1 example;
example.commandId = 134;
example.state = STATID_ERROR;

char *p_Char;
p_char = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&example);
QByteArray qba(p_char, sizeof(p_char));
```

Now I have to write a receiver, but the receiver doesn't know what he gets (`Command1`, `Command2` or something else). He would be able to interpret if he could read out the `commandId` and the state.

At this moment I am able to read out the commandId   like this:

```
commandId = static_cast<uint8_t>(qba[0]);
```

but how could I read out the `State` which is an `enum`?

Comment: They have different amount of special members of different types.

Comment: is the command id unique to all Command1, or all Command2???

Comment: the combination of commandId and state is unique for each Command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`State` values will take the size of an `int`. which means to access it you will do :

```
 State state = (State) (*( reinterpret_cast<const int*>(qba.constData()+1)) );
```

First you reinterpret the `const char` pointer as an `const int` pointer, then you deference it (which means you obtain the value), and you cast this value as an `State`.

In order to access other variables you will start at index `1 + sizeof(int) = 1+ sizeof(State)`

See this [thread about the size of an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c).

Comment: Thanks but the compiler errors with "invalid cast from type 'QByteRef' to type State"

Comment: now it errors with "invalid cast from type 'const char*' to type 'State'"

Comment: try: State state = (State) (*( reinterpret_cast<const int*>(qba.constData()+1)) );. I should think more before posting :).