# What makes a better constant in C, a macro or an enum?

Tags: c, macros, enums

I am confused about when to use macros or enums. Both can be used as constants, but what is the difference between them and what is the advantage of either one? Is it somehow related to compiler level or not?

Comment: I think this is a great question when you consider it like this: What are the differences between using macros and enums for defining constants in C?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In terms of readability, enumerations make better constants than macros, because related values are grouped together. In addition, `enum` defines a new type, so the readers of your program would have easier time figuring out what can be passed to the corresponding parameter.

Compare

```
#define UNKNOWN  0
#define SUNDAY   1
#define MONDAY   2
#define TUESDAY  3
...
#define SATURDAY 7
```

to

```
typedef enum {
    UNKNOWN,
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    ...
    SATURDAY,
} Weekday;
```

It is much easier to read code like this

```
void calendar_set_weekday(Weekday wd);
```

than this

```
void calendar_set_weekday(int wd);
```

because you know which constants it is OK to pass.

Comment: Indeed, but one could equally stick with the macros, and then `typedef int Weekday;` as neither typedefs nor enums are typesafe (in this sense) in C...

Comment: For me, macros are actually a better choice for debugging. I instantly know which symbolic constant corresponds to a numerical value without having to count all its preceding enum members.

Comment: @H2CO3: In `gdb`, I use `p (int)Thursday`, or `p (Weekday)3`.

Comment: Enum is more comfort compare to macro

Comment: Can we change the value of enum at compile time and const is equal to enum or macro

Comment: Also worth noting that if you want to reorder or add a constant in the set, enums automatically update while macros need to be manually recalculated.

Comment: @VarunChhangani Like `enum foo { BAR = 3, BAZ = 1 << 9 }`? Yes

Comment: BTW, it's legal to have a comma after the last item in the enumeration list, so the weird comma formatting isn't necessary.

Comment: @H2CO3: Strictly speaking, that's not an advantage of macros over enumerations, since the latter do let you specify the numeric values of elements, if you want, rather than relying on the default numbering.

Comment: @ruakh Yes, but that provokes redundancy. I'd rather not write `enum foo { bar = 0, baz = 1, bar = 2, quirk = 3 };` just in order to make stuff easier to debug.

Comment: @H2CO3: But you *would* rather scrap enums entirely and use macros plus `typedef int ...` to make stuff easier to debug? De gustibus non est disputandum.

Comment: @ruakh Nah, I just don't want you to exaggerate.

Comment: @H2CO3: I don't understand. How did I exaggerate? I just said that this isn't, strictly speaking, an advantage of macros over enums, because enums offer both options.

Comment: @ruakh I was referring to the "But you would rather scrap enums entirely" part. I wouldn't, but I feel there are cases where macros can be more useful regarding *some aspects* in *some cases.* I don't want to say that enums are useless (because they aren't of course), neither should you imply that I do.

Comment: @jamesdlin I recently found out it was *not* legal in ANSI C. It surprised me (I always thought the main advantage was that it made code generation that little bit easier) but there you have it.

Comment: @Thomas Hm, interesting.  You're right; the grammar for *enum-specifier* in C99 explicitly allows a trailing comma, but the C89 specification does not include that.

Answer (score 22):

A macro is a preprocessor thing, and the compiled code has no idea about the identifiers you create. They have been already replaced by the preprocessor before the code hits the compiler. An enum is a compile time entity, and the compiled code retains full information about the symbol, which is available in the debugger (and other tools).

Prefer enums (when you can).

Comment: I think that enum is more comfortable compare to macro in case of debugging.

Comment: Not arguing, but with `gcc -g3`, you can compile a gdb-friendly executable that retains information about macros.

Answer (score 16):

In C, it is best to use enums for actual enumerations: when some variable can hold one of multiple values which can be given names. One advantage of enums is that the compiler can perform some checks beyond what the language requires, like that a switch statement on the enum type is not missing one of the cases. The enum identifiers also propagate into the debugging information. In a debugger, you can see the identifier name as the value of an enum variable, rather than just the numeric value.

Enumerations can be used just for the side effect of creating symbolic constants of integral type. For instance:

```
enum { buffer_size = 4096 };  /* we don't care about the type */
```

this practice is not that wide spread. For one thing, `buffer_size` will be used as an integer and not as an enumerated type. A debugger will not render `4096` into `buffer_size`, because that value won't be represented as the enumerated type. If you declare some `char array[max_buffer_size];` then `sizeof array` will not show up as `buffer_size`.　In this situation, the enumeration constant disappears at compile time, so it might as well be a macro. And there are disadvantages, like not being able to control its exact type. (There might be some small advantage in some situation where the output of the preprocessing stages of translation is being captured as text. A macro will have turned into 4096, whereas `buffer_size` will stay as `buffer_size`).

A preprocessor symbol lets us do this:

```
#define buffer_size 0L /* buffer_size is a long int */
```

Note that various values from C's `<limits.h>` like `UINT_MAX` are preprocessor symbols and not enum symbols, with good reasons for that, because those identifiers need to have a precisely determined type. Another advantage of a preprocessor symbol is that we can test for its presence, or even make decisions based on its value:

```
#if ULONG_MAX > UINT_MAX 
/* unsigned long is wider than unsigned int */
#endif
```

Of course we can test enumerated constants also, but not in such a way that we can change global declarations based on the result.

Enumerations are also ill suited for bitmasks:

```
enum modem_control { mc_dsr = 0x1, mc_dtr = 0x2, mc_rts = 0x4, ... }
```

it just doesn't make sense because when the values are combined with a bitwise OR, they produce a value which is outside of the type. Such code causes a headache, too, if it is ever ported to C++, which has (somewhat more) type-safe enumerations.

Comment: Can we change the value of enum at compile time and const is equal to enum or macro

Answer (score 13):

Note there are some differences between macros and enums, and either of these properties may make them (un)suitable as a particular constant.

- enums are signed (compatible with int). In any context where an unsigned type is required (think especially bitwise operations!), enums are out.
- if long long is wider than int, big constants won't fit in an enum.
- The size of an enum is (usually) `sizeof(int)`. For arrays of small values (up to say, `CHAR_MAX`) you might want a `char foo[]` rather than an `enum foo[]` array.
- enums are integral numbers. You can't have `enum funny_number { PI=3.14, E=2.71 }`.
- enums are a C89 feature; K&R compilers (admittedly ancient) don't understand them.

Comment: Actually, the size of enumerations is [*not* guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/366033/440302) to be the same as `int` although most compilers in practice will use `int` for binary compatibility reasons.

Comment: +1. People use enum to declare constants way too often.

Answer (score 5):

As a practical matter, there is little difference. They are equally usable as constants in your programs. Some may prefer one or the other for stylistic reasons, but I can't think of any technical reason to prefer one over the other.

One difference is that macros allow you to control the integral type of related constants. But an `enum` will use an `int`.

```
#define X 100L
enum { Y = 100L };

printf("%ld\n", X);
printf("%d\n", Y); /* Y has int type */
```

Comment: In C, `enum` constants are always `int`, there is no such rule about wider types. You might be mixing things with C++?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Ah, caught by another GCC extension. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If macro is implemented properly (i.e it does not suffer from associativity issues when substituted), then there's not much difference in applicability between macro and enum constants in situations where *both* are applicable, i.e. in situation where you need signed integer constants specifically.

However, in general case macros provide much more flexible functionality. Enums impose a specific type onto your constants: they will have type `int` (or, possibly, larger signed integer type), and they will always be signed. With macros you can use constant syntax, suffixes and/or explicit type conversions to produce a constant of any type.

Enums work best when you have a group of tightly associated sequential integer constants. They work especially well when you don't care about the actual values of the constants at all, i.e. when you only care about them having *some* well-behaved unique values. In all other cases macros are a better choice (or basically the only choice).

Answer (score 1):

`enum` has an advantage: block scope:

```
{ enum { E = 12 }; }
{ enum { E = 13 }; }
```

With macros there is a need to `#undef`.

Comment: I would *never* consider giving an `enum` type different values in different places in the same code base any sort of "advantage" in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: If A offers a feature, while B doesn't, then usually A has an advantage over B.

Comment: You can also drop a bowling ball on your foot.  That's not an advantage.