# Utility of macros for enum

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

One header `socket.h` on my Linux system looks like the following.

```
/* Bits in the FLAGS argument to `send', `recv', et al.  */
enum
  {
    MSG_OOB             = 0x01, /* Process out-of-band data.  */
#define MSG_OOB         MSG_OOB
    MSG_PEEK            = 0x02, /* Peek at incoming messages.  */
#define MSG_PEEK        MSG_PEEK
    MSG_DONTROUTE       = 0x04, /* Don't use local routing.  */
#define MSG_DONTROUTE   MSG_DONTROUTE
...
```

Defining an `enum` is sort of an [idiom for creating type-safe-ish constants in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125505/what-makes-a-better-constant-in-c-a-macro-or-an-enum) that the language actually treats as compile-time constants.

My question is : what purpose does the definition of macros `MSG_OOB`, `MSG_PEEK`, … that expand to themselves serve?

Comment: I have never seen it but I guess it overwrites any possible alternative definition so you are sure it is only the enum.

Comment: `MSG_OOB` expand to `MSG_OOB`.

Comment: @GIJoe You may be on to something here. They won't expand to a value the pre-processor can use, but `#ifdef MSG_PEEK` will work as expected if someone needs to write it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The POSIX standard mandates that "symbolic constants" such as `MSG_DONTROUTE` be "object-like macros", rather than enumerants. Defining them to themselves allows them to be used in the context of the enumeration, as well as working properly with, e.g., `#ifdef`.

From the POSIX standard:

> The  header shall define the following symbolic constants 
>   ....
>   MSG_DONTROUTE

And:

> symbolic constant... refers to a C preprocessor symbol (also without arguments).

And finally, from an appendix:

> Where a constant is required to be a macro but is also allowed to be another type of constant such as an enumeration constant, on implementations which do define it as another type of constant the macro is typically defined as follows:
>
> `#define macro_name macro_name`
>
> This allows applications to use #ifdef, etc. to determine whether the macro is defined, but the macro is not usable in #if preprocessor directives because the preprocessor will treat the unexpanded word macro_name as having the value zero.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer rather than Jens Gustedt's also excellent one because of the reference to POSIX.

Comment: The key is in that last quote.

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of these defines is that the application can do something like

```
#ifdef MSG_OOB
  some code here
#endif
```

expansion of macros is not recursive so the evaluation of macro `MSG_OOB` results in the `enum` constant `MSG_OOB` of the same name.

To also have the constants declared as `enum` helps for example when you are debugging.

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong. See @Sneftel's answer.

Comment: @GIJoe This answer is partial, but it complements Sneftel's well.

Comment: @GIJoe, why would it be *wrong*? The question asks for the purpose, and not about the origin of the definition.

Comment: "This allows applications to use #ifdef, etc. to determine whether the macro is defined, but the macro is not usable in #if preprocessor directives because the preprocessor will treat the unexpanded word macro_name as having the value zero."

Comment: @GIJoe the quote does not contradict this answer. There is a difference between the preprocessor's interpretation of the macro in a `#if` directive versus elsewhere in the code (where it expands to the value of the enum).

Comment: Actually, it is affected by this answer. The way it is shown, the ifdef affects what code is executed between it, but thats not the case