# Why does clang's stdbool.h contain #define false false

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer

After being pointed there by a compiler error, I noticed clang's [`stdbool.h`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html) file includes (among other things) the following lines:

```
#define bool  bool
#define false false
#define true  true
```

They're contained in an `#ifdef` block that enforces `__cplusplus` indirectly, hence the c++ tag even though `stdbool.h` is a C header.

What's the need for those defines? I imagine they're required for some preprocessor-related reason but I'd be interested to know what part of the standard or which technical reason makes it so clang has to include those.

Comment: Most likely this is to appease ported C programs that expect `false` and `true` to be macros (e.g. with `#ifndef false` tests).

Comment: Here is a related question, not that the answer is necessarily exactly the same, some of the advantages are identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855326/utility-of-macros-for-enum

Comment: For one thing, it'll cause a warning if someone tries to `#define` them again.

Comment: You should read the comments about GNU extensions.

Comment: What compiler error pointed you there? If it was "redefinition of `false`" or something ... then working as intended :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh it was completely unrelated. A bad macro expansion ended up pulling that file in the error output.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`stdbool.h` is a C header, not a C++ header. It is not usually found in C++ programs because `true` and `false` are already keywords in C++.

Consequently, if a C++ program includes `stdbool.h` it is a fairly clear indication that it is a ported-over C program (e.g. a C program that is being compiled as C++). In this case, G++ supports `stdbool.h` in C++ mode as a GNU extension, per the comments from the [GCC `stdbool.h`](http://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/stdbool.h.html):

```
/* Supporting <stdbool.h> in C++ is a GCC extension.  */
#define _Bool        bool
#define bool        bool
#define false        false
#define true        true

...

/* Signal that all the definitions are present.  */
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined        1
```

Clang, likewise, supports `stdbool.h` in C++ for compatibility with G++.
The values are intentionally defined here to match the built-in C++ type rather than the traditional C99 definitions. They are defined as macros presumably to provide some compatibility with the [C99 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html), which requires:

> The  header shall define the following *macros*: `bool`, `true`, `false`, `__bool_true_false_are_defined`.
>
> An application may undefine and then possibly redefine the macros bool, true, and false.

Answer (score 18):

It was added to suport [GNU mode in C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html), as we can see from this patch [[cfe-commits] r115028](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20100927/034949.html) :

> Define _Bool, bool, true, and false macros in  when we're
>   in a GNU-compatible C++ dialect. Fixes <rdar://problem/8477819>.

so `gcc` supports this as an extension and this modification was made to support that extension.

Although I can not find the original problem report mentioned in the patch.

This is non-conforming as we can see from the draft C++11 standard section `18.10` Other runtime support *[support.runtime]*:

> The header <cstdbool> and the header <stdbool.h> shall not
>   define macros named bool, true, or false.

but `gcc` is not meant to be strictly conforming in GNU mode.

`stdbool.h` is part of C99 and so was not supported by the C++ standard until C++11 which in *Annex D* says:

> For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR,
>   the C++ standard library provides the 25 C headers, as shown in Table
>   154

and includes `<stdbool.h>`.