# Enums or macro. Which is better

Tags: c++

I have to store the multiples values of same type.

I opted for array.

But that array values will be used in the multiple parts of the program.

So i decided to access the array values using Macro.

```
arr[VALUE_1]
```

Here `VALUE_1` is the macro

Another workaround for macro is enums

```
enums{
VALUE_1,
VALUE_2
}
```

I wonder that enums will consume some memory.

Which is better for efficient programming?

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: @venerik Added the C++ tag

Comment: Even if the enum were to consume memory, we'd be talking about something like 8 bytes total. Unless you're on an incredibly memory-constrained system, it's not even worth thinking about.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125505/what-makes-a-better-constant-in-c-a-macro-or-an-enum or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767667/c-enum-vs-const-vs-define

Answer (score 4):

> I wonder that enums will consume some memory.

Enumerators don't exist at runtime. They are **not** objects, but rather constants. And their names are prvalues.

They are substituted by their values right at compile-time. So there is no performance difference by any means.

And follow the general guideline: Prefer `enum` to macros.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, enums are virtually identical to constants at runtime, so there won't be a difference with macros when the programme is running. However, from a source stand point, enums are understood by the compiler as a set of related values bundled into a single *type*. This can be very useful for type checking your code. Besides, it will force you into properly handle your constants, if you weren't already doing it, for a better overall code base.

Just use enums.