# struct as 208 bits long variable

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation

I am trying to make a `struct` that could hold 208 <s>bytes</s> bits. My intentions are using every 3 bits of variables to store 68 values each between 0 and 4.

I currently have this, but am getting quite a few errors:

```
typedef struct {
    uint64_t _1vr = 0;
    uint64_t _2vr = 0;
    uint64_t _3vr = 0;
    uint16_t _4vr = 0;
} TEST;

const TEST test_bits = {
    ._1vr = (BVUS_ZAC1 << 0) | (BVUS_ZAC2 << 3) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 6) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 9) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 12) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 15) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 18) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 21) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 24) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 27) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 30) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 33) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 36) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 39) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 42) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 45) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 48) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 51) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 54) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 57) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 60),
    ._2vr = (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 0) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 3) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 6) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 9) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 12) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 15) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 18) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 21) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 24) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 27) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 30) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 33) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 36) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 39) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 42) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 45) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 48) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 51) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 54) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 57) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 60),
    ._3vr = (BVUS_VISOKO << 0) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 3) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 6) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 9) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 12) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 15) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 18) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 21) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 24) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 27) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 30) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 33) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 36) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 39) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 42) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 45) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 48) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 51) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 54) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 57) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 60),
    ._4vr = (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 0) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 3) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 6) |     (BVUS_VISOKO << 9) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 12)
};
```

- 4x: **Warning    19 (near initialization for 'test_bits') [enabled by default]**
- 4x: **Warning 4 excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]**
- **Error 1 expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token**
- Whole bunch of: **Warning    51  left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]**
- **Error 2 unknown field '_1vr' specified in initializer**
- **Error 20 unknown field '_2vr' specified in initializer**
- **Error 38 unknown field '_3vr' specified in initializer**
- **Error 56 unknown field '_4vr' specified in initializer**

These variables are defined in global scope.

I have no clue whats going on. To be honest I dont see anything wrong (of course I am wrong but...)

**EDIT:**

Doing exactly what WChargin said I still cant get rid of next errors:

- Error    12  (near initialization for 'test_bits._1vr')
- Error    24  (near initialization for 'test_bits._2vr')
- Error    36  (near initialization for 'test_bits._3vr')
- Error    11  initializer element is not constant
- Warning  1   left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]

**EDIT2:**

I am doing this on a 8-bit architecture.

Comment: You can't initialize struct members in the `struct` declaration. Try `struct { int a = 0 };` for a MWE.

Comment: I don't really know what to tell you. I don't have an 8-bit machine handy, and my GCC (v4.8.2) gives no errors. However, under `-pedantic`, I do get four "ISO C90 forbids specifying subobject to initialize" on each of the `._1vr = ` lines—perhaps related?

Comment: @WChargin The errors dissapear if I remove all of the bitwise operations that move bits more than 32bits. So, if I have (BVUS_ZAC1<<31) I get errors.

Comment: bits not bytes, right?

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yeah, my mistake... Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems:

- You can't initialize struct members in your `struct` declaration.
  That is, your `uint64_t _1vr = 0;` statements are invalid.
  That's why you get the "expected…before '=' token" error.
- Presumably, your constants are defined as the wrong size—are they not `long` enough?
  I've just used `#define`s here for simplicity, and it works.

This compiles fine (with `gcc -c`):

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint64_t _1vr;
    uint64_t _2vr;
    uint64_t _3vr;
    uint16_t _4vr;
} TEST;

#define BVUS_ZAC1    0ul
#define BVUS_ZAC2    0ul
#define BVUS_VISOKO  0ul
#define BVUS_NIZKO1  0ul
#define BVUS_NIZKO2  0ul

const TEST test_bits = {
    ._1vr = (BVUS_ZAC1 << 0) | (BVUS_ZAC2 << 3) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 6) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 9) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 12) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 15) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 18) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 21) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 24) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 27) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 30) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 33) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 36) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 39) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 42) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 45) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 48) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 51) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 54) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 57) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 60),
    ._2vr = (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 0) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 3) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 6) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 9) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 12) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 15) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 18) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 21) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 24) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 27) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 30) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 33) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 36) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 39) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 42) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 45) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 48) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 51) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 54) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 57) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 60),
    ._3vr = (BVUS_VISOKO << 0) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 3) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 6) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 9) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 12) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 15) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 18) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 21) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 24) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 27) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 30) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 33) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 36) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 39) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 42) |
    (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 45) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 48) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 51) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 54) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 57) |
    (BVUS_VISOKO << 60),
    ._4vr = (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 0) | (BVUS_VISOKO << 3) | (BVUS_NIZKO2 << 6) |     (BVUS_VISOKO << 9) | (BVUS_NIZKO1 << 12)
};
```

Note, however, that `sizeof(TEST)` yields `32` on my (64-bit) machine.
This may not be what you want.

Comment: Constants are declared in enum. How can I ensure they are long enough?

Comment: @user1806687 See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/366026/732016). Don't define them in an `enum`, I guess.

Comment: sizeof(TEST) == 32!?? wtf?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I am guessing uint16_t gets changed to uint64_t because he's on a 64bit machine.

Comment: Not changed, padded or aligned.

Comment: Oh, I was parsing it as 32 bits, not bytes; it was late. 32 bytes is just 4*8 bytes, due to padding of the struct to a 8 byte border which is the natural alignment for a 64 bit machine. The size of the last member is not changed at all, the padding isn't used for anything. One can usually avoid that padding with some `pragma pack`  or compiler option. That may be necessary in order to be space efficient or in order to match a hardware layout.

Answer (score 0):

On this particular architecture 64bits are defines as long long, so changing the defines @WChargin posted to ULL works.

Comment: Any special reason why you don't use uint64_t instead of some implementation defined integer type if you want 64 bits?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I am not getting what you're saying.

Comment: Instead of `#define BVUS_ZAC1    0uul` write `#define BVUS_ZAC1    ((uint64_t)0)`. That should make it obvious and implementation-independent how many bits the type of the literal has, and should fail to compile in case there is no 64 bit type (not sure whether the standard mandates one).

Comment: Or, even better, just make it an actual `uint64_t` variable—the `#define`s in my example were just so the code would compile.