# What does this enum declaration in C mean?

Tags: c, enums

I am trying to understand some C code in a legacy database. There are constructions there of the form:

`enum {a=0,b,c,d};`

What does this achieve ? In the manuals, I only see constructions of the form:

`enum example{a=0,b,c,d} test1;` and this I understand.

Thanks, Suresh

Answer (score 6):

This defines a set of constants which may be used anywhere with the values

- a = 0
- b = 1
- c = 2
- d = 3

Since we worried less about type safety in legacy C applications, we don't need a specific type for this, or variables directly associated with it

Comment: The question is better suited to SO than to Programmers.

Comment: Enumeration constants are always of type `int`.

Comment: Not quite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c

Comment: Yes, quite. The size of an enumeration *type* is implementation-defined. The *constants* are always of type `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson this is a slightly late response, I confess. Thank you for pointing out that subtle difference; I only clued into what you mean on rereading these comments today.