# gcc warning for different return type

Tags: c, gcc

I have written a library in C that now is going to be used in an embedded processor board. I need to reduce the memory foot print so was going an changing the return type of some functions from int to char (only used to flag errors).

Changing the return type but not changing the variable returned doesn't produce a warning. Is there some way set this in gcc as I want to ensure I've caught all instances.

```
char processSomething (SomeType *something)
{
  int result = 0;
  ...
  do stuff
  ...

  return result; /* no warning */
}
```

Thanks

19 June:
I've added the -Wconversion which has highlighted some interesting things. Two questions with this. One of my functions I take a two character hex string and convert to decimal using

char decimal;

```
decimal = hexstring [0] - '0' << 4 + hexstring [1] - '0'; // for 0 to 9
```

it complains about converting from int to char and from what I can gather is the '-', '+', and '<<' operators all seem to implicitly convert to int. Is this correct or am I interpreting the warning wrong. Or is there a more better way to do this?

Also, when using strtol into an int (complains about 'long int' to 'int') but I can guarantee the value will not be over even short int in size, is it safe to typecast? As in will it truncate the extra (and hopefully zero bytes) of the long? Or does this depend on endianness?

Thanks

Comment: The function return value will be in a register. You have not said which processor, your question only makes sense if it's an 8-bit.

Comment: Note that `char` can be signed or unsigned! Better specify that explicitly. Best use `uint8_t` or `int8_t` from `stdint.h` Especially for embedded devices, this is the recommended way.

Comment: i doubt doing this will help you reduce memory usage.

Comment: If it just to return `true`/`false`, use `bool` (`stdbool.h` - no one will use the reswerved names like `_Bool`).

Comment: As Others already stated: that will only save memory space if the target is 8 Bits. For anything larger, `int` will likely fit into the same register as `char`.

Comment: I doubt this return debacle will save any memory. If it does, it'll be penny pinching at best there will only be a noticeable effect if all usual activity has a long call stack. Or there are recursive functions which have a huge level of recursion. Without a discussion about the library and the data set it normally works on memory reduction can not be advised on. This is very last resort.

Comment: @rhubarbdog Agree returning `char` vs. `int` will likely not save memory.  Other effect: It could make code longer.  But OP is not asking how good this approach reduces memory, just asking how to detect side effects of the attempt.  IMO, using the `enum` approach is a fine idea to get a handle on the range of error  values.  Embedded programming stresses limits of RAM, ROM, Stack, time in strange ways and sometimes even a penny-pinched solution is worth it.

Comment: To answer the question about int to char: `'0'` i.e. character literal is `int`, so other operands are also promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 7):

In this specific case [-Wconversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) should give you the warning you want, in my simple test case (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df79c36c6b45a40)*):

```
char func()
{
    int x = 10 ;

    return x ;
}

int main() {}
```

I receive the following warning:

> warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Answer (score 3):

This is a really bad idea: `char` is a certain size on most embedded systems (usually 1 byte so it's actually an `unsigned char`) and if you end up setting your `int result = 256` somehow, it will overflow and return 0.  Your error just turned into a success.  Crashy crashy (hopefully).  Worse, maybe kill someone with your embedded device.

I know you're trying to fix this but even just returning magic numbers is dangerous.

Instead, declare an enumeration type that is an error.  It will give you type safety (to an extent) and automatically create the correct return size for your functions.

```
typedef enum status {
    STATUS_OK = 0,
    STATUS_ERR1,
    STATUS_ERR2,
// ... etc ...
} status_t;

status_t processSomething (SomeType *something)
{
  status_t result = STATUS_OK;
  ...
  do stuff
  ...

  return result;
}
```

This is much safer and the compiler will allocate only 1 byte for your returns until you have too many to fit, and only then will it make it bigger.
Taken from the current C Standard (C99): http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

> 6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers
>       [...]
>       Constraints
>       The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable
>   as an int.
>       [...]
>       Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration.

Comment: `char` is not defined to be signed or unsigned by the standard. It can even change between compilers for the same architecture unles they use the same ABI/PCS. An `enum` OTOH will be an `int` at least. That will not save anything. (However, it is a good idea to have the returned values as such being enums if that is for an error code).

Comment: Enums are not at "least an int" but at "most an int", at least that's my understanding from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/366026/951784

Comment: I prefer the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3) as a reference. Note that p4 only refers about _compatibility. That's why I would return `(u)int8_t`, but use the enum labels.

Comment: Ok, from the C99, 6.7.2.2p4 says
Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,108) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. [...]

Footnote 108 adds

An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have been seen.

If you return uint8_t instead of enum, you risk overflow very quickly.  256 error codes is pretty reasonable.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting, yeah you seem to be right about that, I should be read more carefully. However, that still does not _guarantee_ `char`, but might allow for it. That is the main point I criticize about enums. It would be much easier if one could specify its type explicitly..

Comment: I'd rather take the extra byte of return size than worry about overflowing the resulting return from an error into a success in an embedded application.  You can always shave a few extra bytes off somewhere else and if you're really THAT hard up, use a bigger part.  The difference in price between for a slightly bigger part is in the pennies range. It's just not a fight worth having in 2015.

Comment: If only the constants are used, the compiler will warn, That can be turned to an error, so I do not see a problem here. The OP seems to have real trouble with memory footprint (I know such situations very well - someone has choosen a cheap MCU whit no option for more Flash/RAM). However, there are other things I would try first.

Comment: Exactly, shave memory elsewhere first before messing with return sizes of all/many functions.

Comment: You have written a fact, then supplied a supporting link that says in most cases my statement is not true. And got voted up?

Comment: Sorry, that link was misleading.  See earlier comments for the reference from the standard: from the C99, 6.7.2.2p4 says Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,108) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. [...] Footnote 108 adds An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have been seen.

Comment: +1 for the enum idea, yet I do not consider OP's approach _bad_, just not likely successful.  BTW: "automatically create the correct return size" is true, but not necessarily the smallest size.  Often depends on compiler options trading speed/size.

Comment: The current standard is C11, although I don't know if that effects the rationale

Comment: I just checked the latest standard and that part didn't change.  I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. This is my first embedded application so I am still learning about all this. The development is on an Atmel based target (currently using Arduino). As I'm having to work within some tight constraints, I'm looking at any options to shave memory. I do like the enum idea. With regards to the char return value only making a difference if the target is 8-bit as a 16-bit register would still take up the same memory, I did realise that but was hoping to save memory from the locally stored 'result' variable. I'll have a play, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Making the return type smaller than int on ARM or PowerPC will just increase the code size and execution time due to additional masking/extending instructions. Make the return type enum and let the compiler to optimize what is possible for given system.