# Why enum's size is not optimized to 2 bytes?

Tags: c

We know that C store enum types internally as `int`, which means that the size of the enum is 4 bytes in 32/64 bit machine.

But considering `int` is signed and range from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, we certainly don't need that many available values. We can use unsigned short (max 65,535) or even unsigned char (max 255) suffices. So my questions are:

Q1-why C don't make enum type store unsigned short/char internally?

Q2-Why we need to use `typedef` to declare an enum e.g

```
typedef enum { N_LEAF, N_INTERNAL } nodetype_t;
```

but we don't need to use `typedef` in struct declaration e.g

```
struct node_s {
   char c;
   int i[2];
};
```

Why we can't make enum declaration the same as struct as:

```
enum { N_LEAF, N_INTERNAL } nodetype_t;
```

Comment: Best practice is to only ask one question per question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say beforehand if sizeof(int) is too big for enum, as some may want it to be as large as that. Anyway, check: [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation) which mentions:

> Normally, the type is unsigned int if there are no negative values in the enumeration, otherwise int. If -fshort-enums is specified, then if
> there are negative values it is the first of signed char, short and
> int that can represent all the values, otherwise it is the first of
> unsigned char, unsigned short and unsigned int that can represent all
> the values. On some targets, -fshort-enums is the default; this is
> determined by the ABI.

You do not *need* to use typedef with enum. The use of typedef is the exact same in struct and enum. Try to create an enum with and without typedef.