# Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always?

Tags: c, enums, constants, c-preprocessor

Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always ?

- Or is it compiler dependent?
- Is it wrong to say, as compiler are optimized for word lengths (memory alignment) ie y int is the word-size on a particular compiler? Does it means that there is no processing penalty if I use enums, as they would be word aligned?
- Is it not better if I put all the return codes in an enum, as i clearly do not worry about the values it get, only the names while checking the return types. If this is the case wont #DEFINE be better as it would save memory.

What is the usual practice?
If I have to transport these return types over a network and some processing has to be done at the other end, what would you prefer enums/#defines/ const ints.

EDIT - Just checking on net, as complier don't symbolically link macros, how do people debug then, compare the integer value with the header file?

From Answers —I am adding this line below, as I need clarifications—

> "So it is implementation-defined, and
>   sizeof(enum) **might be** equal to
>   sizeof(char), i.e. 1."

- Does it not mean that compiler checks for the range of values in enums, and then assign memory. I don't think so, of course I don't know. Can someone please explain me what is "might be".

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c

And this: http://bytes.com/groups/cpp/135139-sizeof-enum-sizeof-int

Comment: From net- on some forum, "I thought an enum was supposed to be as small as needed to hold all of its values, in this case 1 byte." Is it true.

Comment: Thanks to all i am learning few reasonable doubts, which i think will surely help get the concept better.

Comment: i found the answers from "nuriaion" and "lulian Sebaniou" relevant to a part of the question. Anyone ps comment on the correctness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is compiler dependent and may differ between enums. The following are the semantics

```
enum X { A, B };

// A has type int
assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(int));

// some integer type. Maybe even int. This is
// implementation defined. 
assert(sizeof(enum X) == sizeof(some_integer_type));
```

Note that "some integer type" in C99 may also include extended integer types (which the implementation, however, has to document, if it provides them). The type of the enumeration is some type that can store the value of any enumerator (`A` and `B` in this case).

I don't think there are any penalties in using enumerations. Enumerators are integral constant expressions too (so you may use it to initialize static or file scope variables, for example), and i prefer them to macros whenever possible.

Enumerators don't need any runtime memory. Only when you create a variable of the enumeration type, you may use runtime memory. Just think of enumerators as compile time constants.

I would just use a type that can store the enumerator values (i should know the rough range of values before-hand), cast to it, and send it over the network. Preferably the type should be some fixed-width one, like `int32_t`, so it doesn't come to conflicts when different machines are involved. Or i would print the number, and scan it on the other side, which gets rid of some of these problems.

---

**Response to Edit**

Well, the compiler is not required to use any size. An easy thing to see is that the sign of the values matter - unsigned types can have significant performance boost in some calculations. The following is the behavior of GCC `4.4.0` on my box

```
int main(void) {
  enum X { A = 0 };
  enum X a; // X compatible with "unsigned int"
  unsigned int *p = &a;
}
```

But if you assign a `-1`, then GCC choses to use `int` as the type that `X` is compatible with

```
int main(void) {
  enum X { A = -1 };
  enum X a; // X compatible with "int"
  int *p = &a;
}
```

Using the option `--short-enums` of GCC, that makes it use the smallest type still fitting all the values.

```
int main() {
  enum X { A = 0 };
  enum X a; // X compatible with "unsigned char"
  unsigned char *p = &a;
}
```

In recent versions of GCC, the compiler flag has changed to `-fshort-enums`. On some targets, the default type is `unsigned int`. You can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348245/how-is-the-default-enum-size-short-or-no-short-determined-by-the-configure-opt).

Comment: I think now, rather than storing each command in unsigned char variable and equating it to a value, i shall store it in #define, as it has always been done. Enums will face byte-order issues. I think now i understand why #define have always been used for error-codes, state-names, commands... etc.

Comment: It is not completely true there's no difference between enums and #defines: as you said for #defines the compiler doesn't even see the initial token, since it's substituted with the real value by the preprocessor.
The compiler does see the enums though, and if you compile the code with debugging symbols, the debugger will show you the enumerated labels instead of their value, which greatly aids debugging.

Comment: All this talk about #define's... If anyone else is reading this then take it from a guru that the last thing you want to do is use #define's in C++ for constants / enumerates. I'm not adding how and what else to use in a comment, but it is not #define's.

Comment: in the answer, it is unclear what is meant by "the following are the semantics". Are you claiming that the assertions are always true?

Answer (score 18):

C99, 6.7.2.2p4 says

> Each enumerated type shall be
>   compatible with  char,  a  signed 
>   integer  type,  or  an  unsigned 
>   integer type.  The  choice  of  type
>   is implementation-defined,108) but
>   shall be  capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the 
>   enumeration.   [...]

Footnote 108 adds

> An implementation may delay the choice of  which  integer
>   type until all enumeration constants have been seen.

So it is implementation-defined, and sizeof(enum) might be equal to sizeof(char), i.e. 1.

In chosing the size of some small range of integers, there is *always* a penalty. If you make it small in memory, there probably is a processing penalty; if you make it larger, there is a space penalty. It's a time-space-tradeoff.

Error codes are typically #defines, because they need to be extensible: different libraries may add new error codes. You cannot do that with enums.

Comment: Does it not mean that complier checks for the range of values in enums, and then assign memory. I dont think so, ofcourse i dont know :). Can some please show explain what is "might be"

Comment: "The compiler does" is a useless statement. There are many compilers in the world, and some do it one way, and others do it a different way (even on the same hardware). If you want to know what a specific compiler does, you must name the compiler (including version and target CPU and operating system). It may well be that *your* compiler always uses int for enums.

Comment: The second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c) give a different version of the same standard where it says it must be compatible with `int`. Is his version outdated (he links to a draft) or is yours?

Comment: @Norswap I think that answer is a misinterpretation of the (same) standard.

Answer (score 13):

> Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always

The ANSI C standard says:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined. (6.7.2.2 Enumerationspecifiers)

So I would take that to mean no.

> If this is the case wont #DEFINE be better as it would save memory.

In what way would using defines save memory over using an enum? An enum is just a type that allows you to provide more information to the compiler. In the actual resulting executable, it's just turned in to an integer, just as the preprocessor converts a macro created with *#define* in to its value.

> What is the usual practise. I if i have to transport these return types over a network and some processing has to be done at the other end

If you plan to transport values over a network and process them on the other end, you should define a protocol. Decide on the size in bits of each type, the endianess (in which order the bytes are) and make sure you adhere to that in both the client and the server code. Also don't just assume that because it happens to work, you've got it right. It just might be that the endianess, for example, on your chosen client and server platforms matches, but that might not always be the case.

Comment: yes that is the concern, i have transfer some value to be used as command over the network, and i wish to make as efficient and robust as possible, ie y i need opinions what to use for command #defines or enums, the range of commands shall not be more than 20 commands, so according to all in char limit.
I think i shall post it as a new question I would get a better response.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to simply use an unsigned char then. You don't have to worry about endianess or encoding that way.

Comment: maybe you could add a reference to [Should I use cstdint?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6144682/2932052) for the network section

Answer (score 5):

No.

Example: [The CodeSourcery compiler](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp)

When you define an enum like this:

```
enum MyEnum1 {
A=1,
B=2,
C=3
};
// will have the sizeof 1 (fits in a char)

enum MyEnum1 {
A=1,
B=2,
C=3,
D=400
};
// will have the sizeof 2 (doesn't fit in a char)
```

[Details](http://www.codesourcery.com/archives/arm-gnu/msg02684.html) from their mailing list

Comment: if that is the case its awesome.

Comment: that's not true....it's implementation dependent....both codes give output as 4 on my system.Platform - Ubuntu 10.04 (32-bit),gcc compiler

Comment: Not a bad example, but both links http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp (1st) and http://www.codesourcery.com/archives/arm-gnu/msg02684.html (2nd) are broken. (hoping for a repair update.)

Answer (score 2):

On some compiler the size of an enum is depending on how many entry's are in the Enum. (less than 255 Entrys => Byte, More than 255 Entrys int)
But this is depending on the Compiler and the Compiler Settings.

Comment: is there anyway i can force this. A nice input thanks though.

Comment: Because of these Problems in our project (we have to use realy old C compiler) we decided to not use enum. But to define everything with #define

Comment: It's not about the number of enumerator members but rather the range of values they represent. I could have an `enum` containing 2 members: `{apples = 0, oranges = 1000}`. Do you think the compiler can fit those into any `char` ("Byte")? Not without having a mapping between enumerator values and underlying values, which obviously doesn't exist: that would be a nightmare for implementation, performance, and use. An `enum` is really just a way to have some context-sensitive integer type but be able to refer to its members with textual identifiers; members are stored as their numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum fruits {apple,orange,strawberry,grapefruit};  
char fruit = apple;  
fruit = orange;  
if (fruit < strawberry)  
...
```

all of this works perfectly
if you want a specific underlying type for an enum instance, just don't use the type itself.