# Problem when assigning a pointer to an enum variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, enums, warnings, int

I am getting a warning of "assigment from incompatible pointer type".  I don't understand why this warning is happening. I don't know what else to declare "the_go_status" variable to other than an integer. (Note: this is not all the code, but just a simplified version I posted to illustrate the problem.)

The warning occurs on the last line of the example I included below.

```
//In a header file  
enum error_type  
{  
    ERR_1 = 0,  
    ERR_2 = 1,  
    ERR_3 = 2,  
    ERR_4 = 4,  
};  


//In a header file  
struct error_struct  
{  
   int value;  
   enum error_type *status;  
};  



//In a C file  
int the_go_status;  

the_go_status = ERR_1;  

//Have the error_struct "status" point to the address of "the_go_status"  
error_struct.status = &the_go_status;    //WARNING HERE!
```

Answer (score 3):

Because status is a pointer to enum error_type, and the_go_status is a pointer to an int. They are pointers to different types.

Comment: This is true, but what he wants to do seems, and I can't believe I'm finally seeing this as the best phrase to describe it, awfully smelly.

Comment: codeySmurt: Yes, you are correct. &the_go_status is a pointer to an int.

Comment: to be more specific &the_go_status is the address to what the pointer, if it had been declared, points.

Comment: So, for int * pointer; pointer = &anotherPointer you may set a pointer to the address of the other pointer and therefore to that value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is related exactly to your warning or not, but be **very** careful assigning references to local variables to pointers within structs. If `the_go_status` is a local, as soon as your function returns, the reference to that local will become invalid. So, if your code (or someone else's code) uses your instance of `error_struct` outside the function declaring `the_go_status`, things will quickly break.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `enum error_type *` isn't compatible with `int *`, because they point to values of different types (and possibly even different sizes).  You should declare `the_go_status` as:

```
enum error_type the_go_status;
```

Although simply casting the pointer (i.e. `(enum error_type *)&the_go_status`) will make the warning go away, it may result in bugs on some platforms.  See [Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always)

Answer (score 1):

you should declare a pointer if you want to use a pointer:

```
int * the_go_status
```

otherwise you declare a primitive, which is not placed on the heap, but on the stack. (please correct my when being wrong on that)

However, I don't get why you want to use a pointer at all. Just do something like this in your struct definition:

```
enum error_type status;
```

and change your last line to:

```
error_struct.status = the_go_status;
```

Comment: Just declaring a pointer doesn't do any good, you have to point it at something.

Comment: true. As for any other kind of "variable", you have to set it once, so it has a value. However, as this is one of the most basic things of programming, I assumed this being obvious

Answer (score 1):

```
//This might be the simplest 

#include<stdio.h>
typedef enum {err_1=0,err_2=1,err_3=2,err_4=4}error; 
typedef struct
{
    int val;
    error* status;

}errval;

int main() {

    error the_go_status=err_1;  
    errval val1;//just a variable name for the struct
    val1.status=&the_go_status;
    printf("%d",val1.status);
}
```

Comment: this will give compilation error while printf(),

Answer (score 0):

The "the_go_status" should be typed "enum error_type".
You could typedef the enum

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
   
using namespace std;
enum error_type  
{  
    ERR_1 = 0,  
    ERR_2 = 4,  
    ERR_3 = 78,  
    ERR_4 = 9
};  


//In a header file  
struct error_struct  
{  
   int value;  
   enum error_type *status;  
};  


    int main() {
        enum error_type the_go_status;
        the_go_status = ERR_2;
        
      
        
        cout<<the_go_status<<endl;
         
        error_struct p1;
       
        
        p1.value = 6;
        p1.status = (enum error_type *)&the_go_status;

        
        cout<<(*p1.status)<<endl;
        p1.status++;
      
        cout<<(*p1.status)<<endl;
  

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).