# Why does shifting more than the allowed bits still work?

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have an `int8_t` and I wanted to see what would happen if I shift it left further than 8 bits. So this is what I did:

```
int8_t x = 1;

std::cout << (x << 10);
```

For some reason this returns 1024 as if the type contained enough bits to represent that number. I thought that when you shift more than the given bits you would get 0 in all the bits (or signed overflow/underflow which leads to undefined behavior). Also, I ran this code to give me the maximum number of `int8_t`:

```
std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max(); // 127
```

The max number of this type is 127 but shifting it left can make it even go higher than its unsigned type! How is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The arguments to `<<` are being implicitly widened to `int`, and the result of `x << 10` is also an `int`.

Comment: How can I keep it to `int8_t`?

Comment: @user2030677 You can't. You can cast the result after the shift,if you want. Then you get the implementation-defined conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed integer type.

Comment: @DanielFischer ans NPE: Suppose if I shift like: `int8_t y = 10;  std::cout << (x << y);`  then it will return int **?** or output would be `0`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You didn't tell us the value of `x` and how many bits are in your `int`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The operands of the shift operators are subject to the integer promotions, so you always get at least `int`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze `x` is `int8_t x = 1;` from OP

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In that case, there's nothing new, you'll get 1024 printed. The type on the right side of `<<` and `>>` does not influence the type of the result.

Comment: Is there any point in making them `int8_t` in the first place?