# What data type should I use for a general purpose integer?

Tags: c++

What data type should be used for a general-purpose integer in C++?

The obvious answer is `int`, and this made sense in old times where it was commonly 16-bit on 16-bit machines and 32-bit on 32-bit machines. But now 64-bit code is becoming more common, but `int` is often 32-bit on those compilers. So we can't assume `int` is necessarily the "fastest" or largest type for that system any more.

Another problem is propagation of 64-bit values from the size of data structures and files. I know you can store these values in a 32-bit int and get away with it, if the size doesn't get too big. But I want to write code which can handle the maximum size of data, if that's what the user wants. I don't want my code to die if the user opens a 5gb file and wants the whole thing in memory, because the size is stored in an `int` somewhere. 16+gb ram systems will be the norm someday, and I want my code to still work.

I know that there are types such as `vector<T>::size_type` to store that data. But what if size data can come from several different container and stream types? Should I use `size_t` for all integers which may store size information?

So I'm forced to conclude I should use the `size_t` data type (or signed equivalent, I can live with a maximum of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes per data structure for now), and not `int`, for general-purpose use, but this is not what I observe in practice, where `int` is still commonly used.

What integer data type should I use for general-purpose calculations and what are the technical reasons for doing so?

Comment: une "long long" is 64 bit on every os and is supported fron (if I'm not wrong) C99

Comment: It depends on what you want to do

Comment: @GMG, C99 has nothing to do with C++. `long long` has been supported since C++11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use cstdint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144682/should-i-use-cstdint)

Comment: @Nemo The question is which type I should use, not whether I should use the equivalent type from cstdint int or the built-in.

Comment: @NeilKirk: The answers there also answer your question. There is no "equivalent type from cstdint"; that itself is platform-dependent, which is kind of the whole point.

Comment: Is there any evidence that 32 bit arithmetic is any slower than 64 bit arithmetic on a 64 bit architecture? The bit-ness is more about pointer size, is it not?

Comment: @JosephMansfield I'm most concerned with loss of data in 64-bit to 32-bit values.

Comment: If you are really worried about the size of data or rather how long an input might turn out to be. Then you can try long long if "long" is not long enough. Long long can hold an infinite numerical value and even if you multiply two or more long numerical values, it will still be able to handle such a case.

Comment: `"Long long can hold an infinite numerical value"` - false

Answer (score 2):

Depending on a situation, you use different integers. Generally, there are two big classes of integers - these related to the data that your program models (i.e. domain data), and these related to construction of the program itself.

Integers from the program's domain (e.g. user data, the data that your program collects or computes, and so on) should be represented with types providing the specific sizing. In C++ these types are defined in the [`<cstdint>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint). For example, if you need a signed 32-bit type that is portable across all platforms, use `int32_t`; if you need a 64-bit unsigned number, use `uint64_t`, and so on.

If you are concerned with execution speed, use integer types with `fastN_t` suffix, e.g. `uint_fast16_t` for a fast 16-bit unsigned integer.

Integers related to program construction are created when you take size of data structures or subtract pointers. Use `size_t` for sizes, and `ptrdiff_t` for pointer differences.

Comment: `cstdint` is a tighter version of the header for this purpose, I believe.

Comment: +1. But you did not mention `int` (or `unsigned`, `long`, etc.) Is your advice never to use them?

Comment: @Nemo I do not use `int` or `long long` in anything facing the user of my APIs to be as specific as possible about the type in a platform-independent way. I use `int`s and `long long`s as local variables in situations when it does not matter - for example, for loop indexes when I know the bounds are small, for counters internal to my program, and so on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But instead of using int when you know bounds are small, why not use size_t so it's correct no matter the bounds?

Comment: @NeilKirk The problem with `size_t` is that it is unsigned. Therefore, loops that decrement the loop variable (i.e. `for (size_t i = size-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)` loops) will never stop for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is "general purpose". You should use `int` unless there is a reason not to. In fact, the very fact that you use anything other than `int` signals to people reading your code that you are not doing "general purpose calculations". It even says so right in the standard itself,

> Plain `int`s have the natural size suggested by the
>   architecture of the execution environment44 ; the other signed integer types are provided to meet special
>   needs.

If you are indexing into a file that might be very large, you're not doing general purpose calculations anymore. `fseek` takes an argument of type `long`, not `int`. You will use `long` not because it's the correct "general purpose" integer type, but because you have a "special need".

If you use `long` or `long long` for everything then you will confuse people.

Comment: `int` used to have the "natural" size of the architecture but I disagree that is commonly the case on 64-bit systems. `long` is 32-bit in my compiler Visual Studio and I want to open any supported file size. I don't consider opening files a "special need".

Comment: @NeilKirk OK, maybe you don't consider processing > 2 GB files a special need. That doesn't change anything. Use whatever type you need to use when processing files. `int` is still the general purpose type. I checked just now, and doing calculations with `int` takes the same amount of time as doing calculations with `long long` on my system, even though it's 64-bit.

Comment: So that suggests long long should be used instead of int!

Comment: @NeilKirk If you use `long long` then it will be slower than `int` on a 32-bit system. You are still going to have to use it if you want to support > 2 GB files on a 32-bit system. But you really should use `int` whenever you don't need a longer type.