# C++ How to get sizeof(enum) == sizeof(char)?

Tags: c++, enums, sizeof

I would like to know how.

I have looked at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always), and I understand that "The choice of type is implementation-defined.", but I am curious to know how to get 1 instead of 4.

Comment: It's not something you can get, it's how it is. Although it might be possible in C++ 11 (not sure).

Comment: @violet Cat Plus Plus's answer worked. I got 1! :-D By the way, may I ask if you are female or male?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The size of an enum normally shouldn't matter (unless you're creating very large arrays of enums).

Comment: @Keith you are right. I was curious if it was possible to get 1 manually. That is all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++11 introduced a way to change the underlying type of an enum.

```
enum foo : char { ... };
enum class foo : char { ... };
```

Still, you're probably better off with using the default `int` in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

On GCC, you can also use the 'packed' attribute to tell the compiler you care more about space than word alignment / access speed:

```
enum foo { ... } __attribute__((packed));
```

There are similar hints for other compilers too.

(This is useful when trying to avoid any C++11 features that aren't yet supported by your compiler or IDE.)