# -Wincompatible-pointer-types and enum

Tags: c, gcc, enums

Implicit cast from `short*` to `int*` prints the warning about incompatible pointer type (and I understand why).

Implicit cast from `enum*` to `int*` prints same warnig.

There's a tool `snacc` that generates the following code:

```
typedef enum
    {
        CHARGINGCALLING = 0,
        CHARGINGCALLED = 1,
        NONECHARGING = 2
    } ChargedParty; /* ENUMERATED { CHARGINGCALLING (0), CHARGINGCALLED (1), NONECHARGING (2) }  */

typedef struct MSOriginatingSMSinSMS_IWMSC /* SET */
{
    ChargedParty* chargedParty; /* [6] IMPLICIT ChargedParty OPTIONAL */
} MSOriginatingSMSinSMS_IWMSC;

#define BEncChargedPartyContent BEncAsnEnumContent

int BEncMSOriginatingSMSinSMS_IWMSCContent (BUF_TYPE b, MSOriginatingSMSinSMS_IWMSC *v) {
    BEncChargedPartyContent (b, (v->chargedParty));
    ...
}
```

A header file shipped with this tool:

```
int BEncAsnIntContent (BUF_TYPE b, int *data);
#define BEncAsnEnumContent BEncAsnIntContent
```

The call to `BEncChargedPartyContent` prints the warning.

Can I modify the declaration of `BEncAsnEnumContent` so it accepts without a warning pointers to *any* enum, but not `void*` or `short*`?

Of course using `sed` I could replace the macro `BEncChargedPartyContent` with a static function:

```
static AsnLen BEncChargedPartyContent (BUF_TYPE b, ChargedParty *data)
{
    return BEncAsnEnumContent(b, (int*)data);
}
```

But there're too many of them.

Comment: [mcve] please. If possible without that ASN #defines and other unnecessary stuff, just stripped down to the minimum.

Comment: This might be of interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always

Comment: You could simply disable this warning in the places it occurs, using `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored`.

Comment: `int BEncAsnIntContent (BUF_TYPE b, int *data));` has mismatched parentheses

Comment: @JohnZwinck this code is actually illegal... "solving" it by hiding the warning amounts to relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: @basin there's no way to specify "any enum". In general, enums may be different sizes, e.g. the compiler might use 1 byte for an enum with only small enumerators defined, 2 bytes for a medium-size one, and 4 or even 8 bytes for one with large enumerators.  This entire design relies on specific non-standard compiler behaviour.

Comment: @M.M: All you need to make this code "safe" in practice on GCC is a static assertion that `sizeof(EachEnum) == sizeof(int)`.  Of course this may not be technically 100% guaranteed to work on all platforms ever, but in practice it will work fine.

Comment: The code excerpt is missing the definition of `ChargedParty`.

Comment: @Armali fixed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own proposal with a static function sounds not so bad.

> Can I modify the declaration of `BEncAsnEnumContent` so it
>   accepts without a warning pointers to *any* enum, but not
>   `void*` or `short*`?

If you want, you can use a static assertion as John Zwinck hinted at.

```
#define BEncAsnEnumContent(b, d)        ({\
    _Static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof *(d), "wrong data size");\
        BEncAsnIntContent(b, (int *)d); })
```

---

What you think of in your comment below is a viable alternative with the advantage that it allows enumerations of different sizes; this is how I understand what you mean:

```
#define BEncAsnEnumContent(b, d)    MyEncAsnEnumContent(b, *(d))
static int MyEncAsnEnumContent(BUF_TYPE b, int val)
{
    return BEncAsnIntContent(b, &val);
}
```

Comment: A block inside parentheses? Since when is it allowed?

Comment: @basin - Be aware that we are talking about GCC, where this has been possible for, I guess, decades.

Comment: I think of a static function `MyEncAsnEnumContent(BUF_TYPE b, int val)` that accepts a value instead of a pointer. Dereference the value in `BEncAsnEnumContent`, call `MyEncAsnEnumContent`, and pass `&val` to `BEncAsnIntContent()`

Comment: @basin - Yes, using that `MyEncAsnEnumContent()` could also be made to work, but what about your requirement that `BEncAsnEnumContent()` shall not accept `short *`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. In your question post you wrote _… modify the declaration of `BEncAsnEnumContent` so it accepts without a warning pointers to any enum, but not  `void*` or `short*`_; this sounds to me like you wanted to trap those cases where a pointer to `void` or `short` is erroneously passed to `BEncAsnEnumContent()`. Now you speak of _the size of the enum_; this sounds to me like you don't cater for anything else than `enum`s, but you now take `enum`s of different sizes into account, which can occur only when using special GCC directives. Am I misinterpreting what you say?

Comment: No, you understand correctly. Safe enum pointers are more important than not accepting `short*`. And non-numeric pointers like `void*` cannot be dereferenced to `int`, which is good

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that enumerations could have different sizes. I'll add what I understand you think of as an alternative to this answer; I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

The *enumeration constants*, that is the list of values in your enum declaration, are guaranteed to be of type `int`. However, this does not apply to the `enum` variable itself. An `enum` need not be compatible with `int` nor with another, different `enum` type variable. The size can vary from case to case and from compiler to compiler.

This is the root of the problem. If you mix `enum` and `int`, or two different enums with each other, all is fine if they have the same size. They are then compatible and you can convert pointers from one of the types to the other without problems.

However, if they are not of the same size, you cannot do this. It would give incompatible types: you would violate the strict aliasing rule and there might also be alignment issues. Plus the obvious: if you try to read a large chunk of data from a location where only a small chunk of data is stored, there's no telling what you will end up with.

The reliable solution is to change your function to simply use an integer type instead of a pointer:

```
int BEncAsnIntContent (BUF_TYPE b, int data);
```

There doesn't seem to be a reason why they pass the parameter through a pointer in the first place. Keep it simple.

Comment: I cannot change the code that calls the function, because it's generated