# how enums work with undefined values?

Tags: c, enums

```
typedef enum {my_false, my_true = 5, my_maybe = 3} my_bool;

my_bool f(){return 2;}
int g(){return my_true;}

int main (){
    my_bool mb = f();
    int i = f();
    printf("%d--%d\n", mb==i, mb);

    mb = g();
    i = g();
    printf("%d--%d\n", mb==i, mb);

    return 0;
}
```

What is happening when a function returns `enum`?

As I see it, in my code, `f()` can return any number, even if it's not defined inside the `my_bool enum`, but it seems that no matter what I return (like `2` in my example, the value stored inside `my_bool mb = f();` would `1` unless I return `0`or`my_false`.

1. Is this what should happen? does `enum` decays immediately to `int` 
   and thus has no problem with numbers that aren't defined in it?
2. Why gcc generates warning: `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]...  printf("%d--%d\n", mb==i, mb);`? isn't `enum` a `signed int`?
3. why defining the same value with different identifiers ok? (i.e. `typedef enum {xx = 1, yy = 1} zz;`)

Comment: `my_bool f()`...and then `return <int>`..what did you expect?

Comment: `my_bool mb` will have exactly the integer returned by `f()` regardless whether this integer is assigned in `enum my_bool` or not.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I didn't expect. I don't understand what enum should hold in this case...

Comment: Isn't 2 a trap representation for `my_bool`?

Comment: @Scheff so `enum` __is__ an `int` that allows me to return it with a nice and catchy name?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya no, every value of the underlying integer type is fine for a variable of an `enum` type.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK. It's an `int` or a `long long int` depending on the enumerator values. If I only could remember the exact rule...

Comment: At least I found an SO Q&A: [SO: Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1113855/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff: "*Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an
unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined but shall be
capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.*" The enum identifiers have type `int`.

Comment: @CIsForCookies: All `enum` types are _integral_ types, just like `char` and `short` and `int`. That doesn't mean they're literally `int`, but you can cast from one integral type to another.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yepp. Read this in the link above...

Comment: @FelixPalmen My doubt was because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13423732/2858773 answer. Specifically the paragraph starting with *Regarding Trap Representation...*

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I don't think the example in this answer is correct. An important property of a *trap representation* is that it causes undefined behavior when accessed, and I can't find any part in the C standard that states a value not corresponding to an `enum` member would be UB...

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya If this would be the case, a lot of code using `enum` for *flags* would actually be undefined.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I agree. If we agree that the example given there is wrong, there is no confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums can take any value in their range. The range is defined by the bits needed to represent all enumerators. In your case, you need 3 bits for `my_true`, which gives a range 0-7.

Enumerators are essentially named constants, and there's no reason why you can't have two constants that happen to have the same value. Plenty of constants are in fact zero.

Comment: Is taking anything outside this range undefined behavior?

Comment: But as far as I remember, the enum example is often used to explain trap representations. Isn't 2 a trap value for `my_bool`?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: No. Not at all. No idea where that's coming from.

Comment: @MSalters IIRC it was an SO answer. Let me find it.

Comment: @MSalters My doubt was because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13423732/2858773 answer. Specifically the paragraph starting with *Regarding Trap Representation...*

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: That shows a value _outside_ the range of enumerators. In that example, the enumerators require 1 bit, so the value `2` (which requires 2 bits) is outside the range.

Comment: @CIsForCookies standard says that the underlying type has to be `char` or `unsigned int`. There are no N bits types which represents the enums.

Comment: @MSalters if that is the case, you cannot create trap representations with enums. Since you can't fir 2 bits in 1 bit. Even if you `memcpy` a 2 there, it will just take one of the possible 0 or 1. Is the example in the answer no correct?

Comment: @PeterJ: That's not an exhaustive list. Obviously the full list has to include types which can have negative values (the guaranteed range of `char` is just 0-127)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I don't even know what you're trying to say there. The smallest possible object in C is a byte, which takes 8 bits. That can be 7 trap bits and one value bit. Copying a `2` would set the lowest trap bit to `1`

Comment: @MSalters yes that is exactly what I meant (pardon my wordings if it was not clear). So it is not possible to create trap representations with enums and hence the example on that link is wrong?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Trap representations are never _guaranteed_. They are possible, but only _outside_ the binary range of enumerators. E.g. `2*(int)highest_enumerator` might be a trapping value, but `enumerator_A | enumerator_B` may not.

Comment: @MSalters I can't find that possibility for enumerators in the standard, Could you give a hint in which paragraph to look for it please?

Comment: This answer "The range is defined by the bits needed to represent all enumerators" and spec's ""Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type." is contradictory.  If I have an enumerator with values 1,2,3, it certainly must be able to encode at least values 0-127 and not just 1-3 or 0-3.

Answer (score 0):

enums can be implemented as `char` ,`int` or `unsigned int` and it is left for the implementation. From the warning you get the information that your gcc compiler implements the `unsigned int`.

Comment: There are more possible choices than you list here.