# _Static_assert error when expression should be true

Tags: c

```
typedef enum
{
    eval1,
    eval2,
    eval3
} enum_t;
_Static_assert(sizeof(enum_t) == 1, "enum_t must be 1 byte");
char dummy[sizeof(enum_t) == 1];
```

This code compiles if the `_Static_assert` is commented out.  The fact that `dummy` compiles should mean that `sizeof(enum_t) == 1` evaluates to true.

Why is my `_Static_assert` not working?

---

Additional cases:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(enum_t) >= 1, "");   // Passes
_Static_assert(sizeof(enum_t) == 1, "");   // Fails
_Static_assert(sizeof(enum_t) > 1, "");    // Fails
_Static_assert(!(sizeof(enum_t) > 1), ""); // Fails
```

---

I am using clang 13.0.0.

My command-line is:
"C:/Program Files/SEGGER/SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM 5.68/llvm/bin/clang" -cc1 -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -mrelocation-model static -mconstructor-aliases -x c -fno-caret-diagnostics -fno-diagnostics-fixit-info -std=c17 -triple thumbv6m-none-eabi -target-cpu cortex-m0 -target-feature +strict-align -target-feature +soft-float -target-feature +soft-float-abi -msoft-float -target-abi aapcs -mfloat-abi soft -fno-signed-char -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -mllvm -arm-global-merge=false -nostdsysteminc -nobuiltininc "-isystemC:/Program Files/SEGGER/SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM 5.68/segger-rtl/include" "-isystemC:/Program Files/SEGGER/SEGGER Embedded Studio for ARM 5.68/include"  -D__SIZEOF_WCHAR_T=4 -D__ARM_ARCH_6M__ -D__SES_ARM -D__HEAP_SIZE__=0 -D__SES_VERSION=56800 -D__SEGGER_LINKER -DDEBUG=1 -DUSE_RTT=1 -DSTM32G031xx -D__STM32G0xx_FAMILY -D__STM32G031_SUBFAMILY -DARM_MATH_CM0PLUS -sys-header-deps -Werror -dwarf-version=4 -debug-info-kind=standalone -debug-info-macro -debugger-tuning=gdb -mllvm -generate-arange-section -exception-model=dwarf -gpubnames -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fmath-errno -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fshort-enums -fno-common test.c -emit-obj -o test.o -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

Comment: Maybe your compiler allows zero-size arrays as an extension? Try `sizeof(enum_t) == 1 ? 1 : -1` as the size.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I verified that my compiler gives me an error on a 0-sized array.

Comment: Please try the array size I suggested.

Comment: That does give me an error.  If I change it to `char dummy[sizeof(enum_t)];` I can see that `dummy` has a size of 1 in my map file.  So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't trust the map file. It probably means that your compiler allows zero-size arrays in certain situations (when the zero is computed and not hardcoded, perhaps?). I couldn't reproduce this (either all zero-size arrays are rejected, or all are accepted, depending on flags). What compiler did you use, including version and flags?

Comment: You were *so* close to giving a [mcve] but for some reason you chose to replace a critical part with `...`.  Next time, it would be better to give compilable code so people can easily help you out without guesswork.

Comment: @hyde I work in embedded systems.  Adding `main` and printing the size is non-trivial.  Hence I tend to look at the map file.

Comment: @Graznarak: You can add `void foo(void) { __asm__("# sizeof (enum_t) = %0" : : "i" (sizeof (enum_t)) ); }`, compile with `-S` to generate assembly, and then look in the assembly for the “# sizeof (enum_t) = ” line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always)

Comment: @user3840170: No, that is not relevant. The issue here is not particularly what the size of the enumeration type is but why `_Static_assert` and the array declaration test appear to be indicating conflicting things.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If that is so, then it should be clarified in the question body.

Comment: @user3840170: The body states the fact that the declaration of `dummy` compiles indicates the expression evaluates as true, conflicting with the `_Static_assert`. The body explicitly asks the question “Why is my `_Static_assert` not working?”, not “Why is the size not one byte?”

Comment: I have tried testing the enum size against 1, 2, 4, 8.  All fail.  Also note the additional `_Static_assert` lines that were added to the question.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If I remove the `-fshort-enums` comand-line argument, then `_Static_assert` works as expected.  It appears that there is a bug related to `sizeof()` when `-fshort-enums` is used and finding the size of an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers accept 0-length arrays.  For example, [testing GCC 11.2 on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYj0AB1QFQlsGZzcPSOjYgV9/IJZQ8K4LTCsbASECJmICBPdPXMtMazji0oJ0wJCwvQUSsoqk6s6mvxastq4ASgtUV2Jkdg5kBFKAanR3FgBPAFIAVgAhDS2AEXWAZm2OMdpOTd5PDi1SVE5HBYUJqcwF9YAmI55SAk0zmMANYgI5HAB0YKh0JhADZ9JxJNcAfdOLwFCANH8AWM4LAkGgWBE6GFyJRCcT6OFkMAuFxPnw6AQwhiIMEUcE/KVVpxfoS2IIAPIMWg8268LAsQzAcTi0j4Yi1GwAN0wGLlmFUtVczN5vD8zIuctoeGCxG5ziwKIIxDwLD1YyoBmACgAanhMAB3QURRh6mSCERidhSAPyJRqFG6XIGIwgUzGcwm4IYyBjVARQoMdUAWgA6mJaAt85qbUx0fklXF7AwnC5Kl5a81MtlkjEs90qqQou24s3Wjk8gV6n1O%2B1K3Uin1%2B0NBx1GmPeo0Z63RuNJtM9DbMDMeOdLsi5Q8OKoABywnOwyQLYDIZALOngz4LCCOUgLXCEEgfb65BbOIkSWIH8fhGXh/nFEZgVBCEYTgqF4SNJFSBuO5j3RTFsUg0g8UQEAJgICIdTJCAKSArx8CIQd%2BEDURxFDGjwxUdQ5W3XdeE9c0IgdBEOCuFCUWPQUdSIggFlQKgFjPC8rxvO8Hy4J8XwAykwhA0ZwJxaCwUheC4N45DUN4dCLEwiCtCg3jPkPNC0SwiyxlVYgYjsSQgA), we can see that GCC happily compiles a 0-length array and only warns about it if the `-pedantic` option is used.

Therefore, you should not assume that just because `char foo[x];` compiles that `x` is positive.  If you don't want to use `_Static_assert` and instead want to do your assertions with using array sizes for some reason, you can do something like:

```
char foo[condition ? 1 : -1];
```

Comment: Why reach for flimsy empirical testing on Godbolt, when you have [official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length)?

Answer (score -1):

The C standard states that each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type - and that the choice of type is implementation-defined. (ISO/IEC 9899:2018 6.7.2.2 4)

Thus, **typically**, in C an `enum` is an `integer` type not a `char` and so I would expect:

`sizeof(enum_t) == sizeof(int)`

Thus, for a typical 32 bit system, `sizeof(int)` is 4 - I suspect this is what you are seeing...

Some compilers do have a language extension that allows you to specify the size of the enumerated type... standardising this has been discussed, but it is not in C18 nor (yet!) a candidate for C2X.

Comment: Enumeration constants have type `int`, but an enumeration type itself has a type compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type, per C 2018 6.7.2.2 4. So it can be one byte.

Comment: Let me expand my answer then... you are quite right that the Standard *allows* that...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always?noredirect=1&lq=1