# Advantage of array of enum over constant and macro?

Tags: c++, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use #define, enum or const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112433/should-i-use-define-enum-or-const)
>   [Advantage and disadvantages of #defines vs. constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944041/advantage-and-disadvantages-of-defines-vs-constants)

How enum will be more useful than #define and const. 
memory and code visibilty point of view and readability point of view.
can I convert (type cast) enum to array of int, If I have taken all value within integer.

Example:

```
    class MapPlt_clContainer { 
    public:  
    enum tagVectorType {       
    enVTAll = 0,       
    enVTPolygon,       
    enVTLines 
    }  
    };  

    tVoid MapPlt_clRender::vDrawLineClass( MapPlt_clContainer::tagVectorType* )
```

While calling function enum pass

```
vDrawLineClass( ClassArray_Group ); //Working
```

While calling array base address pass

```
int test[3] =  
{       
5,       
6,       
7, 
};   

vDrawLineClass( test); //Not Working
```

Error!!

Should it type cast it automatically? or it is compiler dependent. In my case it is giving error.

Comment: FWIW, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112433/should-i-use-define-enum-or-const is tagged as C++, and this question is tagged as C, and there is a distinct difference in how `const` works between the two.

Comment: Also: there are no classes in c, and the `public:` label is not allowed in a struct (or union) definition. `::` is always a syntax error in C, and the parentheses in `&(ClassArray_Group[5])` are not needed, which implies that the interviewer is not sure about his syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I made very confusing code to demostrate this senario. but I want to know if I pass array base address to function which is expecting enum address then will it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum` is a separate **type** unlike `#define` and the language (with the help of compiler) will help you ensure you are not mixing values of different **types** (even if they are of the same numerical value).

Additionally the value of an `enum` is available to the debugger whereas the original meaning of the `#define` is lost during the pre-processing time (before the code generation has even begun).

Type-casting an `enum` to an `int` is an automatic built-in process while the opposite conversion is trickier as not all the `int` values could be valid for your particular `enum`.

Modern compilers will also warn you if you have used all the possible `enum`'s values in a `switch` statement that has no `default` clause, something that cannot be checked for `#define`s

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an enum as an integer in C++ you have a smell.  An enum defines a type, and only the values of that type should be used.  (I realize this isn't enforced and the enum can be interpreted as an int, but with C++ it generally shouldn't).

Also, a big pet peeve of mine: Don't put "Type" in the name for an enum in C++.  The values of an enum are not "types" (in the C++ sense of the word).  As soon as you start doing template code, you will HATE all the enums with the word Type in their type name.

Also, any time you are trying to typecast in your design, you are doing it wrong.  That is an awful smell in C++.  You shouldn't have to do it, and you certainly shouldn't design it into your code (i.e. use it as a "feature").

Finally, this part:

```
int test[3] =  
{       
5,       
6,       
7, 
}; 

vDrawLineClass( test); //Not Working
```

This is a straight up ugly hack.  Do what you say, say what you do:

```
MapPlt_clContainer::tagVectorType test[3] =  
{       
MapPlt_clContainer::enVTAll,       
MapPlt_clContainer::enVTPolygon,       
MapPlt_clContainer::enVTLines 
};

vDrawLineClass( test);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points made in other answers, I would like to add the following:

If you have multiple types and you need to iterate on them, you will have to use an array of constants, which will be something like this:

```
const int states[] = {STATE_1,STATE_2, STATE_3, STATE_4 };
int numStates = sizeof(states)/sizeof(state[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
    // Do something with states[i]..
}
```

With enumerations, this can be simplified as

```
enum states{cState_1 = 0, cState_2, cState_3, cState_4, cNumStates};
for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
    // do something with i
}
```