# Is it better to use #defines, enumeration values or const ints to define constant values?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use #define, enum or const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112433/should-i-use-define-enum-or-const)

Recently I've found it convenient to use using enumeration values to define constants but I'm interested to know what are the pros and cons of using const ints, #defines vs enumeration values for constants?

Answer (score 2):

I believe using `#define` for constants is a relic of C, because in C there was not always a  `const` keyword. Now you can use `const int` instead, and should. As for `enum`, C++11 provides some neat features with `enum` that are worth checking out, and they will probably suit your needs better than anything if you are going to have multiple constants that are somehow related.

Comment: There *is* a `const` keyword in C. It's just less useful because when C says it requires a "constant expression", it means a literal, not a `const`.

Comment: I don't think the const keyword has always been there though. It was introduced later on, after the introduction of C++

Comment: It was definitely [present in C89/ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Keywords). That's after Bjarne started working on what would become C++, and (according to Wikipedia) even a few years after they started calling it C++. But I doubt C started adopting C++ features that early (it took them until 1990 to put `//` comments into the standard, and that's a really simple feature compared to `const`). It appears K&R didn't have `const`. But I failed to find a source, both for it originating in C and for it coming from C++.

Comment: Also, constants are numbers, and enums have (some kind of) a type in C++03 and can have a strong type in C++11. So different solutions suit different problems.

Comment: Nevermind, you are right. C++ introduced `const` (in 1981 or earlier) as described by [Sibling Rivalry: C and C, Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/sibling_rivalry.pdf) (page 5)