# #define equivalent in c++

Tags: c++

g++ 4.7.2

Hello,

I am coming from C89 and now I am doing c++ using g++ compiler.

Normally I do things like this:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 64
#define DEVICE "DEVICE_64"
```

What is the equivalent of doing this in C++?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: its #define - what am I missing?

Comment: I saw many answers that `const` is equivalent to `#define`. `const` is *not exactly* an equivalent to `#define`. For example, you can have a pointer to a `const`, but not to a `#define`. Plus, `#define` are lost when the preprocessor runs. Why don't you use `#define`, if you need `#define`?

Comment: What works with the C preprocessor works with the C++ preprocessor.  If you're hoping that 'const', or 'constexpr' are equivalent, they're not.  However, they are often better choices than relying on the preprocessor.  Variables (even const ones) have scoping rules that are more useful than #define, as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#define` is there in C++. So you can write the same code. But for constant quantities like this, it is better to use the const keyword.

```
const int ARR_SIZE = 64;
const std::string DEVICE("DEVICE_64");
```

Comment: That seems like the way to go. Even though #define can be included. I really prefer to use the c++ way of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: @ctor `const char[]` is better than `const std::string` IMO. No dynamic allocation, and it can be treated like constexpr.

Comment: Note that the definitions of constants should generally appear in a ".cpp" file, not in a header (".h") file -- otherwise, you can end up with multiple conflicting definitions at link time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `const` in place of #`define`

```
  const int ARR_SIZE = 64;
  const char DEVICE[] = "DEVICE_64";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define constants using the `const` keyword:

```
const int ARR_SIZE = 64;
const char DEVICE[] = "DEVICE_64";
```

Answer (score 3):

It’s even better to use anonymous namespace for that (restricted to current file):

```
namespace {
    int const ARR_SIZE = 64;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: @wilx: Because those constants now carry a type. `#define` introduces only a literal, not a genuine variable. Also, macros pollute the global scope -- which variables do not.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I am not questioning the `const` but the unnamed `namespace`.

Comment: Anonymous namespaces does not restrict to a current file. It's static in translation unit.

Comment: @wilx: in this case I agree with you: you most probably don't need the namespace here since the variable is `static` (`const` at file scope implies static in C++).

Comment: @AlexandreC. - Re: "those constants now carry a type": `64` has type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

## #define is fine !

Excepting type checking, most of C code compile without change with a C++ compiler. So #define is still valid in C++.

you might want to take a look to other stackoverflow entries like :

[Should I use #define, enum or const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112433/should-i-use-define-enum-or-const)

[What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler)