# How to make TypeScript enum restrict to specific number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use a numeric enum type to set a page's access code:

```
export enum AdminAccess {
  None = 0,
  Dashboard = 1 << 0,
  ModifyUserInfo = 1 << 1,
  Publish = 1 << 2
}
```

And I want the route to take a parameter which is type AdminAccess, such that it can only choose between the values above:

```
export interface AuthRouteProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
  path: string;
  pageIdentity: AdminAccess;
  exact?: boolean;
}
```

However the type check didn't work as I expected, the check passes as long as I input number. But what I want is that you can only input `AdminAccess.None`, `AdminAccess.Dashboard` and etc.

```
<AuthRoute
  path={"somepath"}
  pageIdentity={AdminAccess.ModifyUserInfo} // pass check
  children={<ModifyUserInfoPage />}
/>
<AuthRoute
  path={"somepath"}
  pageIdentity={897654987} // also pass check
  children={<ModifyUserInfoPage />}
/>
```

How can I make that work?

Comment: also see [microsoft/TypeScript#17734](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17734)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is possibly a duplicate of ["What is the significance of `enum` in TypeScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168952/what-is-the-significant-of-enum-in-typescript).  Translating the answer there to your problem yields something like this:

For better or worse, numeric enums in TypeScript are assignable both to and from `number`, which directly leads to the problem you're seeing.  You might have better luck abanadoning `enum` in favor of a combination of a `namespace` and a `type` using explicit [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types), like this:

```
export namespace AdminAccess {
  export const None = 0
  export const Dashboard = 1
  export const ModifyUserInfo = 2
  export const Publish = 4;
}
export type AdminAccess = typeof AdminAccess[keyof typeof AdminAccess];

const good: AdminAccess = AdminAccess.ModifyUserInfo; // okay
const bad: AdminAccess = 289849284924; // error
//    ~~~ <---
// Type '289849284924' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2 | 4'.(2322)
```

Note that the computed enums like `1 << 2` need to be replaced with their numeric literal values like `4` for this to work (numeric computations won't result in numeric literal types).

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&jsx=1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgQQBMUBLBfbXddOAbwCg45RJY5sIF14A5TvALxwADI2bho8Dl3gARJOgAWAIwhIohOEICMYlpPaducALIRCJAGYBPAKrpgUAJIJLELXABMeiW2nGABQBXZQAbEiUPABYAbnoAX3p9NhhrMDwiUnJKDBohVPSISwJiMgoqdABtAGtgayK4AuAGzLKc6gBdOPp-eABzCHMALhKs8tyPVuyKgDozCxt7Rxc3GLgAenW4CGqkax6jeGUkQhGp8eoPTwAOAE5rqNubx89Yja3HKGh6TaYmAD9AXAADwAWnBPy2ABU0ngAOQ3e4vB5PKJwuARRAQeAKdAkPrIMJ4GDuJpwOHCOAAHzg2mpXnpaJmAApPABmTyeACU9CAA)